# Golf a Custom Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence, fibonacci

The [Fibonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) is a fairly well known thing around here. Heck, it even has its own tag. However, for all that, we sure like to stick to our roots of `1, 1, ...` (or is it `0, 1, ...`? We may never know...). In this challenge, the rules are the same, but instead of getting the `n`th item in the Fibonacci sequence, you will get the `n`th item in the Fibonacci-esque sequence starting with `x, y, ...`.

## Input

Three integers, in whatever order you want. `n` is the index (0 or 1 indexed) of term in the sequence for your output. `x` and `y` are the first two items in your current program run's Fibonacci sequence.

## Output

The `n`th term in the Fibonacci sequence starting with `x`, `y`.

## Test Cases

(0-indexed)

```
n   x     y     out
5   0     0     0
6   0     1     8
6   1     1     13
2   5     5     10
10  2     2     178
3   3     10    23
13  2308  4261  1325165
0   0     1     0
1   0     1     1
```

(1-indexed)

```
n   x     y     out
6   0     0     0
7   0     1     8
7   1     1     13
3   5     5     10
11  2     2     178
4   3     10    23
14  2308  4261  1325165
1   0     1     0
2   0     1     1
```

## Caveats

Assume `0 <= x <= y`.

Please note your input order (must be constant).

Comment: Can we take a list as input?

Comment: @BusinessCat you mean like `[1, 2, 3]`? Yes. Whatever you need to accept 3 integers.

Comment: @StephenS How about taking an input as `n,[x,y]` where `n` is a number and `x` and `y` are numbers in a list? That's probably being a little too flexible though ;)

Comment: @Tom as long as all you are doing is accepting 3 integers, I don't care how you format your input (so yes, that would be acceptable. You only can't use anything in the input besides the 3 integers as information).

Comment: [Related (Numberphile)](https://youtu.be/D8ntDpBm6Ok), [Related (OEIS)](https://oeis.org/A247698) (I was hoping the Brady Numbers would be a test case...)

Comment: @CAD97 I'll add them, I had forgotten about them :)

Comment: I honestly don't understand why this isn't being considered as a dupe. In most languages, surely, it's simply going to be a case of replacing the 2 initial values of x & y with input values? I've seen the dupe hammer swung on questions that differ a *lot* more than these two.

Comment: @Shaggy it was dupe hammered (not 5 votes) then undupe hammered (not 5 votes). Dunno who unduped it.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/85727/20260)

Comment: There are currently no testcases for `n=1` (or `0` if indexed as such), do we need to be able to handle this?

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam yes, editing in, thank you

Comment: [Quite related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/58419/42545) The only difference in that challenge is that you have to first work backwards until you find the "first item" in the custom sequence.

Comment: Can I `-1`-index? Return `y` for `n == 0`, `x+y` for `n == 1`, and so on?

Comment: @Scrooble As long as you return `x` for `n = -1`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
+¡ạ
```

Takes **x**, **y**, and **n** (0-indexed) as separate command-line arguments, in that order.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@699aOHDXQv///9v/N/Q4L8xAA)

#### How it works

```
+¡ạ  Main link. Left argument: x. Right argument: y. Third argument: n

  ạ  Yield abs(x - y) = y - x, the (-1)-th value of the Lucas sequence.
+¡   Add the quicklink's left and right argument (initially x and y-x), replacing
     the right argument with the left one and the left argument with the result.
     Do this n times and return the final value of the left argument.
```

Answer (score 11):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>14</s>  9 bytes

```
l~{_@+}*;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@59TVx3voF2rZf3/v5GCkYKhIQA)

Input format is "x y n".
I'm still a noob at this, so I'm 100% sure there are better ways to do this, but please instead of telling me "do this" try to only give me hints so that I can find the answer myself and get better. Thanks!

Comment: `ririri` can be shortened to 2 bytes. `fI` can be shortened to 1 byte.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: @Dennis improved! Thank you! And thanks for the welcome.

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>27</s> 26 bytes

Nothing fancy here, just a standard JS Fibonacci function with the initial values of 0 & 1 removed.

```js
n=>g=(x,y)=>n--?g(y,x+y):x
```

---

### Try it

```js
f=
n=>g=(x,y)=>n--?g(y,x+y):x
o.value=f(i.value=13)(j.value=2308,k.value=4261)
oninput=_=>o.value=f(+i.value)(+j.value,+k.value)
```

```css
*{font-family:sans-serif;}
input{margin:0 5px 0 0;width:50px;}
#o{width:75px;}
```

```html
<label for=i>n: </label><input id=i type=number><label for=j>x: </label><input id=j type=number><label for=k>y: </label><input id=k type=number><label for=o>= </label><input id=o>
```

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 37 bytes

```python
f=lambda x,y,n:n and f(y,x+y,n-1)or x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59mm5OYm5SSqFChU6mTZ5WnkJiXopCmUalToQ3k6xpq5hcpVPwvKMrMKwEKG@kY6RgaaP4HAA)

0-indexed, you may need to adjust the recursion limit for `n≥999`

Answer (score 6):

### Python 2, 40 bytes

0-indexed
[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@5@nk6iTZJuZV1BaoqHJlVqRmqwOEkjSSdROslbXyuMqKMrMK1FI/P8/2tBAx0jHKBYA)

```
n,a,b=input()
exec'a,b=b,a+b;'*n
print a
```

Comment: Haha not subject to a recursion/stack limit unlike some other answers. Nice trick.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Thanks! But recursive lambda beats me anyway :D

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 30 bytes

```hs
x#y=(f!!)where f=x:scanl(+)y f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#Zc7NCsIwEATgu08xpR6ySCE/REXIwxRtsKBRWsHk6eMmXgzucb5h2Bz75ITvOnpfp2WCd/G0nsdwEztK8Pk@zgEOlwc2AIYB9UREj0QIJXwuc3hhCyE5lARbe/KPFGFf6diQ@iVlGrNslqC/1k5qNk2cVju0o6aM8i@moDb5Aw) 0-indexed. Use as `(x#y)n`, e.g. `(0#1)5` for the fifth element of the original sequence.

The most likely shortest way to get the Fibonacci sequence in Haskell is [`f=0:scanl(+)1f`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89/56433), which defines an infinite list `f=[0,1,1,2,3,5,8,...]` containing the sequence. Replacing `0` and `1` with arguments `x` and `y` yields the custom sequence. `(f!!)` is then a function returning the nth element of `f`.

Answer (score 5):

### Mathematica, 36 bytes

```
LinearRecurrence[{1,1},{##2},{#+1}]&
```

input

> [n,x,y]

Comment: You can use `##2` instead of `#2,#3`.

Comment: very nice! fixed!

Answer (score 5):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 40 bytes

```powershell
$n,$x,$y=$args;2..$n|%{$y=$x+($x=$y)};$y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyVPR6VCR6XSViWxKL3Y2khPTyWvRrUaJFChraFSYatSqVlrrVL5//9/0/@G/w0B)

Answer (score 4):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 38 bytes

```
{({}[()]<(({}<>)<>{}<(<>{}<>)>)>)}{}{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@1@tUV0braEZa6MBZNjYadrYASkNMGmnCYK11UD4/78xl6EBlzEA)

```
{({}[()]<                      >)}     # For n .. 0
         (({}<>)<>            )        # Copy TOS to the other stack and add it to...
                  {}                   # The second value
                    <(<>{}<>)>         # Copy what was TOS back
                                  {}{} # Pop the counter and the n+1th result
```

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, 27 bytes

```
->a,b,n{n.times{b=a+a=b};a}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [TAESGL](https://github.com/tomdevs/taesgl), 4 bytes

```
ēB)Ė
```

1-indexed

[**Interpreter**](https://tomdevs.github.io/TAESGL/v/1.3.1/index.html?code=XHUwMTEzQilcdTAxMTY=&input=NyxbMSwxXQ==)

**Explanation**

Input taken as `n,[x,y]`

```
 ēB)Ė
AēB)     get implicit input "A" Fibonacci numbers where "B" is [x,y]
    Ė    pop the last item in the array
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
;SḊµ¡I
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@28d/HBH16GthxZ6/v//P9pIxyj2v6EhAA)

**Explanation**

```
   µ¡  - repeat n times (computes the n+1th and n+2th element):
 S     -  take the sum of the elements of the previous iteration (starting at (x,y))
;      -  append to the end of the previous iteration
  Ḋ    -  remove the first element
     I - Take the difference of the n+1th and n+2th to get the n-th.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 85 bytes

```
l(0,X,Y,X).
l(1,X,Y,Y).
l(N,X,Y,C):-M is N-1,P is N-2,l(M,X,Y,A),l(P,X,Y,B),C is A+B.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcwxDoMwDAXQvadgjNWfKA6CoRuEdgMxwgkqpEggGDg@OEZ/efa3vO1rWv/2OJfrSsZjwoyJ3CsZVs/qQR3pY/tiOYrBMsYHAcn02jYkHJUtIea6ebcuv63gJXIgr2oR5ws1S6I6oJJ0avYIkq8OJUrI4kfuBg)

0-indexed.

Comment: Could you edit this answer? I seem to have accidentally downvoted it the day you posted it.

Comment: @EsolangingFruit done

Answer (score 3):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 77 bytes

```
f(N,Y,Z):-M is N-1,f(M,X,Y),Z is X+Y.
l(N,A,B,X):-asserta(f(0,A,B)),f(N,X,_).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/prolog-swi#JYy7DsMgDEX3fkVGrN4gDE1UdUufUzJDlipDkCplKv1/aojOcnx97RzVhICZLu3YfFIztYyoRngEwlwSfwz6sElrwBVeektK6/e3qKhMyYhQfni8See8qQ5GGAhy1IuxVHZn4VbdohPu1dnACo86ODhI8Nw3DtaZM062Z7xI/wE)

Started off golfing [Leaky Nun's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/121135/69074) and arrived at something completely different.

This one has a rule for `(Nᵗʰ, (N+1)ᵗʰ)` in terms of `((N-1)ᵗʰ, Nᵗʰ)` and uses [database management](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=db) to assert 0ᵗʰ and 1ˢᵗ elements at runtime.

`f(N,X,Y)` means `Nᵗʰ` element is `X` and `(N+1)ᵗʰ` element is `Y`.

Answer (score 3):

## R, 39 bytes

```
f=function(x,y,n)'if'(n,f(y,x+y,n-1),x)
```

A simple recursive function. Funnily enough this is shorter than anything I can come up with for the regular Fibonacci sequence (without built-ins), because this doesn't have to assign `1` to both `x` and `y` =P

Calculates `n+1` numbers of the sequence, including the initial values. Each recursion is calculates with `n-1` and stopped when `n==0`. The lowest of the two numbers is then returned, giving back the `n`-th value.

Answer (score 3):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 24 bytes

```matlab
@(n,x)(x*[0,1;1,1]^n)(1)
```

Input format: `n,[x,y]`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#NcvLCoAgFIThfU/R8hiDOMeUIILeQ2zpsrVvb3bbfTPwl3EbrbVtlxPVSJ2SA1eC@TiN0LQiAf1z2QxF4k3@5EdFCggP6ZAU@tgjefAN2Yd6t2DW2KN2AQ)

Answer (score 3):

## x86 machine code, 7 bytes

`EDX = x = fib[1]`, `EAX = y = fib[2]`, `RCX = n` (1-indexed)
returns in EAX.  Works in all 3 modes (16, 32, and 64).
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVbbbuM2EH3XVwxQGIkTy5YcJxvb3QJpkocssC3Q9iFAYBiUNLaZlUiVpGJ5i367OyQlXxJvBQSSyblwzpw5DNMaiyTfhILpYjudwkLJAooNMKHXqEAKWBlT6slgoA1Lv8k3VItcrvupLAZ/V6gNl0IP4vFVNP40Gg9smJC1QVMpyN6EXJSVCY2kD4NLVIPR@Hp0G11/@qn9CCh1msskQaXh8f6Z8mdgVgjOFR4fnnpQKtSo3lADUtSNWXGxBMw1WmeFplJCkz083j0HS4rFckiYxjjSRpHp3Mg55Q9OrE2CAOxTyLfvNb2R1T1INgbhRWV8ZremQPUrA2tuVu5gC660gYwvufHOukrc2zmfRWewf6g2j4SH9@7P@6cnMBJEVVDB3j0tSvdmeQ/GcPSQ@wrTb5SWGeDmTAODDFNeUIXuAPAS9fvjmQ/0mqB793MpyzkKozb7QEZKoPZB@AusFSu1PcWKL1fwxvIKe7BgPNdQCc2XAjM6dlEyhT5/A9LUYT4hbLNDECZNCyDyZrVUOzjozy@SyS6KkoYRwhZLe1LQEtaUiQmwHbfLX@7vgfnPRBpDyK1XSKehghPMpVjqNlZCHkTFPN8hhQ0yCS4kuRSotaVLVYKsFFVtWE7OfYG1mTfn//BMIZPwj8@RI9t390Wx@mIEl0DvWQssRYSLz3D9I/uhtU@P7T/Dufu4uO66/QM6WSNeVLmPEEcAA2BZ5n9iagE96PDEO3GRepwz/o7R6RGj3zE29Yw9JqJbHb/j1B6vPUj/Ult4jucN4j9/Jv52fZup3x9BbXjiJ8nBQENrKRJ0CpYqCXd//f4Ew2DaFADQiXvQGZ7oTy6JhKW0sqJ29lSwdfDVduLZgb3na7piiqU7Fw@DdWkxcEktiDatW0kZceuknHT4QvBMOP@W596/XemgyPjCvVx9QRCwnOYL4ptWp@ZOXAL/8r10IABqbumjy8v4ZmYrEIebWd1sDkdusz7cZO3m1dBtbg6O5npLsQ9qSxc8CfYmaIs/qscFvPHTrTfae@2hnWPNzTkJdRduRmFCRLj79SmwsklYI/QHaaVphENKA/EIYHgV3QKMhjdxYKcBNJKmVrklg7sj2sk1qhIps9eMtSJ1uHXBbTYryabSezi31AzSH1vK5JgoEV09GdYkaJUw7pK4f@5BDedk@hLNus290YONX4qbpYdngDCE32SjVLIspeb0g6klSJU16v1Kg/0d@pkUGLip9D2s7cBC0yjC7/hMdJ85caV85/wybhP2QK9Z6Ve7tmZ7nzlJsSrZTH3gck1ODtmHy7DjLsmWa67RHyAir/j/MNoDssNouIPNHSNLIKoxgVPPFF5JVRTmtz2onBBHMdw9PBCeqcwITU3iocucmFKQnlmdF3QX5bk1JULI3TXRwHtSq71Ut5g7nczqYNr3CnmsAdRD5Vn1WtHRaO6WaHpg/79xub7K7I@vtjz7g0L6fqar5WHo913ZS6JXxDCkQev@uFcnOmWlYrvdjrZX2zj6Dw)
(64-bit NASM source with a _start that parses 3 integers from argv strings)

```
0000000000401070 <cfib>:
  401070:       eb                      .byte 0xeb      # jmp rel8 consuming the 01 add opcode as a rel8
0000000000401071 <cfib.loop>:
  401071:       01 d0                   add    eax,edx
# loop entry point on first iteration, jumping over the ModRM byte of the ADD
  401073:       92                      xchg   edx,eax
  401074:       e2 fb                   loop   401071 <cfib.loop>
  401076:       c3                      ret
```

This "jumps" into the loop with machine code that decodes 2 different ways: with a `jmp +1` when falling into the loop from the top of the function, or with that `01` byte being an ADD opcode when the `loop` instruction jumps backwards.  Equivalent to `jmp .entry` but with only 1 byte outside the loop instead of 2.

(Credit to [@Ira Baxter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765317/can-assembled-asm-code-result-in-more-than-a-single-possible-way-except-for-off/10766612#10766612) for pointing out the general idea of falling into a loop with 1 byte outside that consumes some loop bytes to do something different on the first iteration, e.g. the opcode for `cmp al, imm8` as a 1-byte encoding for a jump forward by 1.  I got lucky that `01 add` could be consumed by jmp rel8 to skip a total of 2 bytes without needing a `66` prefix for `cmp ax, imm16` or being in 16-bit mode.  01 or 03 add didn't work well as a modrm for anything like `add r/m32, imm8`; we need to avoid a memory operand.  Note that this trick is *not* good for performance on some modern CPUs, e.g. AMD that caches instruction boundaries in L1i tags, and probably not newer Intel/AMD with uop caches.)

Stripping labels lets objdump decode as the CPU would on the first pass:

```
cfib:
  401070:       eb 01                   jmp    0x401073   # jmp rel8 = +1
  401072:       d0                      .byte 0xd0        # jumped over
  401073:       92                      xchg   edx,eax
  401074:       e2 fb                   loop   0x401071
  401076:       c3                      ret
```

It's easy to see that the EDX input will be the EAX return value for ECX=1 (exit right away, `loop` is never taken so `add` never runs).

Use `strace ./custom-fib 14  2308  4261` to see the full integer value passed to the `exit()` system call before truncation to an 8-bit exit status.

In 32-bit mode, the same machine code is callable with GCC regparm(3) calling convention as `__attribute__((regparm(3))) unsigned custom_fib(unsigned y /*eax*/, unsigned x /*edx*/, unsigned n /*ecx*/);`, returning in EAX as usual.

---

### Without the 2-way decode hack: x86 machine code, 8 bytes

0-indexed `n` in RCX,  `x` (`fib[0]`) in EAX, y (`fib[1]`) in EDX - note opposite arg order

```
0000000000401070 <cfib>:
  401070:       e3 05                   jrcxz  401077 <cfib.done>
0000000000401072 <cfib.loop>:
  401072:       0f c1 c2                xadd   edx,eax
  401075:       e2 fb                   loop   401072 <cfib.loop>
0000000000401077 <cfib.done>:
  401077:       c3                      ret
```

This way shows off x86's [`xadd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/xadd) instruction, normally only used with a memory destination and a `lock` prefix to implement `fetch_add`.

The reg,reg form of `xadd` decodes to only 3 uops on Intel Skylake, [same as `xchg reg,reg`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45766444/why-is-xchg-reg-reg-a-3-micro-op-instruction-on-modern-intel-architectures) (https://uops.info/).  (The `loop` instruction is slow on Intel so this is hardly optimized for speed.  If you want a speed-efficient asm implementation, unroll by 2 to remove the xchg as shown [in my SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659715/assembly-language-x86-how-to-create-a-loop-to-calculate-fibonacci-sequence/32661389#32661389) using clever loop setup to avoid excess branching for odd vs. even `n` for standard 0,1 Fibonacci.)

Comment: While it is a neat trick to re-use the 01h as a jump displacement, am I missing anything or could you equally well drop the EBh byte by defining the entrypoint to be within the loop as in https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132981/tips-for-golfing-in-x86-x64-machine-code/218097#218097 ?

Comment: @ecm: actually yeah, good point, that would get us down to 6 bytes.  I often forget about putting the function entry point somewhere after the first byte.  I think in this case I'll leave this answer as-is, because I've linked it from a few places as an example of this trick, which is useful if you need something else before the loop, or as part of a larger function.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
⁽+dḞi
```

Takes input as `[x, y]` then `n`.

[Try it online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwi4oG9K2ThuJ5pIiwiIiwiWzAsIDBdLCA1XG5bMCwgMV0sIDZcblsxLCAxXSwgNlxuWzUsIDVdLCAyXG5bMiwgMl0sIDEwXG5bMywgMTBdLCAzXG5bMjMwOCwgNDI2MV0sIDEzXG5bMCwgMV0sIDBcblswLCAxXSwgMSJd)

Explanation:

```
   Ḟ   # Create an infinite list from the initial vector [x, y] from:
  d    # a dyadic,
⁽      # single element lambda
 +     # which adds its two arguments.
    i  # Index into that list with the second input (n).
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 15 bytes

```
VR<2-M[R!+v]R_;
```

`_;` is no longer needed on the latest version of Braingolf, however that's as of ~5 minutes ago. This could be 13 bytes by removing that.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 112 bytes

1-indexed.

```python
import itertools
def f(x,y):
 while 1:yield x;x,y=y,x+y
def g(x,y,n):return next(itertools.islice(f(x,y),n-1,n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#PcxBCsIwEIXhfU8xywRHMatCxNPYqQ6kkzKd0uT0MSq4fXzvb7ysWQ3YSC3ntA0TzTC7gtXHAY4XJ4IQK1OaoNz6fK9YTvXLnh@G4qOS7SogVMz9SxfeEj/I/WIo59Cpb6uyWL9eMeDo2xs)

Comment: Erp, too late and too big.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP>=7.1, 55 Bytes

```php
for([,$n,$x,$y]=$argv;$n--;$x=$y,$y=$t)$t=$x+$y;echo$x;
```

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3d0a076a75c2163d9f443a59f165aaf955d2a2af)

## PHP>=7.1, 73 Bytes

```php
for([,$n,$x,$y]=$argv,$r=[$x,$y];$i<$n;)$r[]=$r[+$i]+$r[++$i];echo$r[$n];
```

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c1acd204195b92546d7b998c39234efb2e567aef)

Comment: Taking advantage of strange PHP's evaluation order: `$y=+$x+$x=$y`. Also, you can use just `$n--` instead of `$i++<$n`.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 7 bytes

```
:"wy+]x
```

Output is 0-based.

Try it at [MATL Online!](https://matl.io/?code=%3A%22wy%2B%5Dx&inputs=10%0A2%0A2&version=19.11.0)

#### Explanation

Let the inputs be denoted `n` (index), `a`, `b` (initial terms).

```
:"     % Implicitly input n. Do this n times
       %   At this point in each iteration, the stack contains the two most
       %   recently computed terms of the sequence, say s, t. In the first
       %   iteration the stack is empty, but a, b will be implicitly input
       %   by the next statement
  w    %   Swap. The stack contains t, s
  y    %   Duplicate from below. The stack contains t, s, t
  +    %   Add. The stack contains t, s+t. These are now the new two most
       %   recently comnputed terms
]      % End
x      % Delete (we have computed one term too many). Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 2):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 36 bytes

```
?sdsbsa[lddlb+sdsbla1-dsa1<c]dscxldp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/dc#@29fnFKcVJwYnZOSkpOkDeLkJBrqphQnGtokx6YUJ1fkpBT8/29orGBkbGChYGJkZggA)

`0`-indexed. Input must be in the format `n x y`.

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp, 49 Bytes, 0-indexed

```
(defun fib(n x y)(if(= 0 n)x(fib(1- n)y(+ x y))))
```

I'm a Lisp noob so any tips would be appreciated ;)

#### Explanation:

```
(defun fib(n x y)                                  | Define a function taking 3 arguments
                 (if(= 0 n)x                       | If n = 0, return x
                            (fib(1- n)y(+ x y))))  | Otherwise, call fib with n-1, y, and x+y
```

Answer (score 2):

## br**nfuck, <s>39</s> 29 bytes

Thanks to @JoKing for -10!

```
,<,<,[>[>+>+<<-]<[>+<-]>-]>>.
```

TIO won't work particularly well for this (or for any BF solution to a problem involving numbers). I strongly suggest @Timwi's [EsotericIDE](https://github.com/Timwi/EsotericIDE) (or implementing BF yourself).

Takes `x`, then `y`, then `n`. 0-indexed. Assumes an unbounded or wrapping tape.

#### Explanation

```
,<,<,            Take inputs. Tape: [n, y, x]
[                While n:
  > [->+>+<<]      Add y to x, copying it to the next cell along as well. Tape: [n, 0, x+y, y]
  < [>+<-]         Move n over. Tape: [0, n, x+y, y]
  >-               Decrement n.
] >>.            End loop. Print cell 2 to the right (x for n == 0).
```

Comment: Why do you bother moving x and y when you can just move n? [Try It Online](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fxwYIo@2ide207bRtbGJtQCybWDvdWDu9//8B)

Comment: @JoKing Considered that (but longer on my own), but it doesn't quite work, unless OP allows "`-1`-indexing".

Comment: Oh, just add a `>` to the end or swap x and y order

Comment: @JoKing My palm hit my face quite hard just now. Thanks!

Comment: Why did you bother to censor "brain" but not the second word in the programming language's name?

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 29 bytes

```c
f(n,x,y){n=n?f(n-1,y,x+y):x;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bdBNbsIwEAXgNTnFiIoqphMUJxWiTQMHqVgE5wdL7lA5prKFuHqNrbJAUXcz732bGZENQvgnSUKd2@5jNK08rY7b5DFR8hAi36eEFh27UE27sGQcHdoXx95tdfWSDHw1ktI4NHoQCOLYaFgu4/bD4JLM/gLoqK2SWXQENYxGm5NSaVSffI/wHHoEnrM7slNU/IPcFJUT9K0D69P5op0jxFPAIjgWK92ZsybIq@TqPS99UeYb/1qs@a/oVTOMPgtPqMVbfgM)

This implementation is 0-based.

Comment: Nice, and welcome! [Here](https://tio.run/##HY3hCoIwFEb/@xQXI9joGlMjqmU9i2xOB3aLqbAhvnpr9P07hwOfKnql4s6SGhfd3adZ2/dxeETDCD0GvlJDzwRFiQH9IfCbl1u0NMOrtcQ4rBmkfVxShuV7nSMYVtYIVS0uCKfqXHIu/5Hr5sURCJlt8avM2PZTLNJjo67iBw)'s a prettier TIO setup for testing, should you choose to use it.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
`©GDŠ+}®@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@59waKW7y9EF2rWH1jn8/x9trGNooGMSCwA)

**Explanation**

```
`           # split inputs as separate to stack
 ©          # store n in register
  G         # n-1 times do
   D        # duplicate top of stack
    Š       # move down 2 places on stack
     +      # add top 2 values of stack
      }     # end loop
       ®@   # get the value nth value from the bottom of stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 44 bytes

0-Indexed

```lua
n,x,y=...for i=1,n do
x,y=y,x+y
end
print(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/lua#@5@nU6FTaaunp5eWX6SQaWuok6eQks8FEqvUqdCu5ErNS@EqKMrMK9Go0Pz//7@h8X8jYwOL/yZGZoYA)

Answer (score 1):

## Axiom, <s>88</s> 57 bytes

```
f(k,x,y)==(repeat(k<=0=>break;c:=y;y:=x+y;x:=c;k:=k-1);x)
```

this would pass the test proposed (0 indexed)

```
(14) -> f(5,0,0)
   (14)  0
                                                 Type: NonNegativeInteger
(15) -> f(6,0,1)
   (15)  8
                                                    Type: PositiveInteger
(16) -> f(2,5,5)
   (16)  10
                                                    Type: PositiveInteger
(17) -> f(10,2,2)
   (17)  178
                                                    Type: PositiveInteger
(18) -> f(3,3,10)
   (18)  23
                                                    Type: PositiveInteger
(19) -> f(13,2308,4261)
   (19)  1325165
                                                    Type: PositiveInteger
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Klein](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Klein), 18 + 3 bytes

This uses the `000` topology

```
:?\(:(+)$)1-+
((/@
```

Pass input in the form `x y n`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 37 bytes

```
\d+
$*1
+`(1*) (1*) 1
$2 $1$2 
 .*

1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#LcoxDoAgEETRfk4xBSaIidlZhCt4CQsL738FRLB5f5PZJZ53u54NIQnbHZVWDoTgDOqAewLUmtFYYBQrNCwsdDidMuQOMzwbD6/9Kt@rzWjGZ/7teAE)

0-based, takes `x y n` separated by space. Calculates in unary.

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 32 bytes

```
Prompt N,X,Y
While N
X+Y➡Z
Y➡X
Z➡Y
DS<(N,0
End
X
```

Answer (score 1):

## k, 15 bytes

```
{*x(|+\)/y,z-y}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/k-ok#DcS7EYAgEAXAVl6mKOp9hHG8VoypAURqRzbYnu665PlbH3cU/26l9Zp92nOb5gACWRzzmMeCgGBMEIgpFEzGClG6cEpk138)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 24 bytes

```
n->x->(x*[0,1;1,1]^n)[1]
```

Input format: `(n)([x,y])`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pari-gp#Xc1BCoAgFIThfadoqfEC55kRRF5EbBm0kYgW3d40CLTt98PM1i5tDL29eyvuzinCDIJfg3Tw8Tj3cIlNGClSUl7K5qPxJfwJNXEiQ6YkqGRMXJpOpAnVATKyVhMNPObR@AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 39 bytes

```
{for(n=3;n<$1+2;)$++n=$n+$(n-1);$0=$n}1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/awk#TYyxDsIwDER3f4UHD60ipJxNQqTQ32E0Eivi20PqImB55zv7PJ63@2PxzbpfBUn7Kin5Jp5k8RPWLnmaF8YozJyZf6T6nRFskeAvgZFOKWEOIhNmScMcxKWRTbXPQWyMYLvkxnzWiv2ZFtTyBg)

Takes inputs as `n x y` 0-indexed

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 11 bytes

```
?ß´UWV+W :V
```

[Try it online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=P9+0VVdWK1cgOlY=&input=MTAsMiwy)

---

### Explanation

```
(Inputs U, V & W line up with n, x & y in the challenge.)
     :Implicit input of integer U.
?    :Ternary to check if U is currently >0.
ß    :If not, call the function again, with the arguments...
´U   :U-1,
W    :W,
V+W  :and V+W.
:    :Ternary "else", i.e. if U=0
V    :Return V
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 58 bytes

```
int f(int n,int x,int y){return n<3?n<2?x:y:f(n-1,y,x+y);}
```

This function is 1-indexed.

Alternatively, one could write the following lambda with recursion, for 55 bytes:

```
interface B{F f=(n,x,y)->n<3?n<2?x:y:B.f.f(n-1,y,x+y);}
```

This requires the following description, which isn't usually counted in Java Lambdas:

```
interface F{int f(int n,int x,int y);}
```

### Test

```
public class Main {

  static
  int f(int n,int x,int y){return n<3?n<2?x:y:f(n-1,y,x+y);}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] tests = {
      {6, 0, 0, 0},
      {7, 0, 1, 8},
      {7, 1, 1, 13},
      {3, 5, 5, 10},
      {11, 2, 2, 178},
      {4, 3, 10, 23},
      {14, 2308, 4261, 1325165},
      {1, 0, 1, 0},
      {2, 0, 1, 1}
    };

    for (int[] test: tests) {
      System.out.printf("%2d %4d %4d %7d%n", test[0], test[1], test[2], f(test[0],test[1],test[2]));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, 25 bytes

Although this is quite old, and there has already been a Mathematica answer using `LinearRecurrence` built-in, mine solution is shorter.

```
{##2}.Fibonacci/@{#-1,#}&
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 30 bytes

```forth
: f 1- 0 ?do tuck + loop nip ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//WymkKRjqKhgo2KfkK5SUJmcraCvk5OcXKORlFihY/zdSMFIwNACq0fsPAA)

Input Order is `x y n`

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 24 bytes

```
{($^x,$^y,*+*...*)[$^n]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NctBDsIgFIThfU8xaYhRJIQHQrpovYiRxoWstJq6KamcHVsad98k/7zv48PlZ8QuoMvznvlJMB8FP3IpJT9cmB@uKYfXiNZCQZ0FWreANtAGDQu7ghQ09CoDAyo5GWijGpy0K7H636kAcwV8bhE169EtM@DL@lRXKf8A)

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, <s>44</s> 39 bytes

<sup>[crossed out 44 is still regular 44 ;(](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)</sup>

```
DEF F N,X,Y
IF!N THEN?X
F N-1,Y,X+Y
END
```

Recursive function; prints the result once N reaches 0, ends with a stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 23 bytes

```
J.)QWgJlQ=aQ+@Q_2eQ)@QJ
```

[**Test suite**](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=J.%29QWgJlQ%3DaQ%2B%40Q_2eQ%29%40QJ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B0%2C0%2C5%5D%0A%5B0%2C1%2C6%5D%0A%5B1%2C1%2C6%5D%0A%5B5%2C5%2C2%5D%0A%5B2%2C2%2C10%5D%0A%5B3%2C10%2C3%5D%0A%5B2308%2C4261%2C13%5D%0A%5B0%2C1%2C0%5D%0A%5B0%2C1%2C1%5D&debug=0)

0-indexed, input format: `[x,y,n]`.

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 8 bytes

```
~{.@+}*;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7NCsJADITveYoB6aWC5MddF3rxXQSlUKqot9K@@rZZ9yCaw8B8TCa53Yfr6/LsH@88NlNepsN5P7ddnpuxzQyfogHYgelDxCU6SSQ/RIwC6gagBTEpqtui7OiUyFAtYB5TIzVOwFGjbD2lTIPE8H2W/x6RcmMF)

Takes input in order `x y n`. Actually generates first *n*+1 values and pops last.

Explanation:

```
~{.@+}*; Full program, implicit input
~        Evaluate
 {   }*  Pop n and repeat:    Stack: x y
  .        Duplicate y               x y y
   @       Get x                     y y x
    +      Add                       y x+y
       ; Pop last
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), <s>110</s> 105 bytes

```
listen to N
listen to X
listen to Y
cast Y
while N
let Z be X-0+Y
let X be Y
let Y be Z
let N be-1

say X
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in, with each input on an individual line in the order `n`, `x`, `y`)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <s>16</s> <s>15</s> 13 bytes

```apl
⊃(1↓⊢,+/)⍣⎕⊢⎕
```

Takes input in the form f x y n

1 fewer byte thanks to TessellatingHeckler

2 fewer bytes thanks to Adám

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKM97f@jrmYNw0dtkx91LdLR1td81Lv4Ud9UIAdIghT8VwCDNC4DBQMuUy4Ez5DLDM4zROGZKphyGcF5RgpGXIYGCK6xgYWCiZGZIZehMQA)

### Old answer

```apl
{⊃(1↓⊢,+/)⍣⍺⊢⍵}
```

Takes input in the form n f x y

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 27 bytes

```
n:?
y:?
+?
Fn,z:y,y:x,z+
Oy
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/z/Pyp6rEoi17bnc8nSqrCp1Kq0qdKq0ufwr////b2j838jYwOK/iZGZIQA)

Just implements the standard Fibonacci algorithm of `x, y = y, x+y` but with `x` and `y` set by the input rather than as \$0, 1\$ or \$1, 1\$

Answer (score 1):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn), [9 bytes](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn)

```
á‹-²À-'Z"
```

[Try it!](https://zippymagician.github.io/Arn?code=Wz8xXz8yeytdPyA=&input=NiAwIDEKNSAwIDAKMTAgMiAy)
Takes input in order `n, x, y` separated by spaces

## Explained

Unpacked: `[?1_?2{+]?`

```
  [       Begin sequence
      _   Variable initialized to STDIN; implied
    ?     Indexed
      1   Second entry
      _
    ?
      2   Third entry
    {     Block (calculates all other entries)
      +   Last two entries added
    }     End block; implied
  ]       End sequence
?
  _       Implied
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pl`, 38 bytes

```perl
($a,$n)=<>;($_,$a)=($a,$a+$_)while$n--
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19DJVFHJU/T1sbOWkMlXkclUdMWLJSorRKvWZ6RmZOqkqer@/@/IZchl9m//IKSzPy84v@6vqZ6BoYG/3ULcgA)

Output is 0-indexed.  Input format is:

```perl
x
y
n
```

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 16 bytes

```
:?!v1-}:@+{
{n;>
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/38pescxQt9bKQbuaqzrP2u7///@6ZUZQbGgAAA)

**Explanation**

```
:?!v        # if n is 0 move to next row
    1-}     # decrement n and move it to bottom of stack
       :@   # save the largest number for next iteration
         +  # add the current numbers
          { # move n to top of stack
{n;>        # print bottom of stack (smaller number) and exit
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 5 bytes (10 nibbles)

```
=@.~~$+<2
```

Input is `[x,y] n`.

```
=@.~~$+<2
  .~~       # append until null (here this means forever)
     $      # starting with first arg
      +     #   sum of
       <2   #   take 2 elements
=@          # finally, get the second-arg-th element
```

[image]

---

If we prefer to input `x`, `y` and `n` as individual numbers, instead of combining `[x,y]` as an array, add 1 byte (2 nibbles):

either `=_.~~:$@+<2` (`:$@` combines arg1 and arg2)
[image]
or `=+$~.~~_+<2` (`_` treats all args in STDIN as an array, but now we need to add one to the index (`+$~`) since we've prepended a useless value to the start of the sequence)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), 8 bytes

```
=A,B:z+y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/39ZRx8mqSrvy/38jYwMLBRMjM0MFQxMA)

Takes input as `x y n`, where `n` is 1-indexed.

### Explanation

```
=A,B      Set sequence start to first two inputs
    :     Mode: Sequence
     z+y  Each item in the sequence is the previous two added together

          If there is a third input, that input is `n`. Get the `n`th (1-indexed) item in the sequence
          If there is not a third input, output the whole sequence.
```

Comment: Note current version uses `Z` and `Y` instead of `z` and `y`