# Is it a fibonacci-like sequence?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, integer, fibonacci, subsequence

The [Fibonacci Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence) is a sequence of positive integers where the first two elements are 1 and the rest are the sum of the previous two. It begins \$1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13\$ and continues forever.

But what if you started with numbers other than \$1, 1\$? You could start with \$3, 4\$ and have the sequence go \$3, 4, 7, 11, 18, 29\cdots\$. Or you could start with \$2, 9\$ and have it go \$2, 9, 11, 20, 31, 51 \cdots\$.

Your challenge is to take a list of positive integers and determine if it could be part of some Fibonacci-like sequence. Essentially, determine if for each element but the first two, it's equal to the sum of the previous two.

### Testcases

Truthy:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
[6, 9, 15, 24]
[49, 71, 120, 191, 311, 502]
[3, 4, 7, 11]
```

Falsy:

```
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[3, 4, 6, 8, 9]
[3, 9, 12, 15, 31]
[3, 4, 6, 10, 16]
[1, 1, 1, 2]
```

You can assume the input will be (non-strictly) increasing and have a length ≥ 3.

Comment: Will input always contain at least 3 numbers? Or will `[1]` and `[1,1]` consider valid?

Comment: @tsh Input will always contain at least three numbers

Comment: Suggest adding or changing a *falsy* testcase to one that fails just at the beginning (to edge testcase backwards calculations). eg `[3, 4, 6, 10, 16]`

Comment: @Noodle9 Added.

Comment: Add Lucas numbers (Start with 2, 1)

Comment: @Fmbalbuena Those aren't increasing (\$2\not\le1\$).

Comment: @att What about 1, 2?

Comment: @Fmbalbuena: That's just the standard Fibonacci sequence shifted by one position.

Comment: If you want just the increasing part of the Lucas numbers, start with 1, 3.

Comment: Suggested test case: `[1, 1, 1, 2]` (all sums of adjacent pairs except the last appear in the sequence, but output should be falsey)

Comment: What, exactly, is a "Fibonacci-like" sequence?

Is that simply one in which every third element is the sum of the previous two, or what other rules does your definition of "Fibonacci-like" rely on?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin No, every element but the first two is the sum of the previous two.

Comment: @emanresuA I cite no source for this and I suggest that while that might describe "a Fibonacci-like" sequence, it's not enough to define "the Fibonacci sequence"… else why use your specific wording?

I see the usual 1,1,2… as a misstatement and the Fibonacci sequence actually starts 0,1,1, because of the immense philosophical, not the tiny arithmetic difference between 0 and 1.

Test that by projecting backwards through 0…

1,1,2 looks good; 0,1,1 beautiful. No other starters, including the test cases here, come close to showing apparent importance.

Just a thought and please, test it.

Answer (score 11):

## [Shue](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242897/golf-the-prime-numbers-in-shue), 149 bytes

```
=R
1,R=<,R
1<=<1
,<=*,
,*=*,
1*=i
i*=*i
,,R=t,R
it=t1
,t=T,
iT=T1
1,T=1,
T=L
L1=L
L,=L
LR
*=Xe
1t=e
1T=e
i,T=e
1e=e
ie=e
ei=e
e1=e
e,=e
,e=e
e=Xe
XeR
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVVRb9MwEH73r7DKA3FrCtbeqhmEoGNI04pKBpO6gtz0ulpK7Mh2Nqax3z7OSdul3Yq2VLr4zt99vjvfpeVNWFpzcK@L0rpAHXDqbzxxIKhErZ/ZotQ5JG7WSZLJLzn9e3EhWZclsq196DBC5rCglQGfqRISzQaE4uMgINGs06k13ETtXb1eWEczqg3VDTI@elFDlJnjlox@Fxedh@0VYW@1sWVvU9d6/phM7uGSL6cy@8Iyz@Pa8VbaA/2h8gqGzlmXLDrflPPgKER1QC9toNlSOZUFNN5md1Qt4gqrwLa599WtCUS0wB6eTOEmgE8m2bTh3Y32WZEORydvh6Oj3RjxgMqZ@CJNt5TRc9MqiC20UcE6j5F6CMnKrcph25JrU1t035e5Dklddrbpqjx2VY15iLuo21n0CxWyZZKzdssV/UtnqzI5YDsFiQf/lfQ22bT1GioY4/SR9YBNxGDK2N1/qtzKMlI/xXzXrlYLz5uImtrBH8iqAEnGabuAaxCm21Q3a1KtjL4C1NF@q5sDCjtHLXUV1Or1Euc8GltFqxFHCpPY2Axc/26RPVzKuvo@Vn@N2M4da13v1oEOVgn6l3jj96gyeOGvx68ZfU/FILMmaFPBFjISKT6LVHUxtnnWCFvvK3MJSQ4m8awn2GPk@uSJHdhexCk2jSOmnobulijesZ8M7LQ36yHHimEwvdvrvXMtO5fX5ib7BtLZS6eK9UQai71U5iqDAkzwVDmgpfVez/C@sbWxm3BW5nQGS3WlbeVY/Jq/oj8/jk@/nn6hn0enKT37PqRHozEdpcfDMf1@fDakn0afhySzcwwLv@@dezkmgo/lIcf3oTwUhB/KLie8G6XoSk00LjXhCAoI0kEGBAWZcqJTmQp0T6XgJJUn5EREwaMYk648ByKCRJGi0DxKAXEZBegoRBQcBa9t0eUcxvcYGQ7lGzF9bkaEaFPGzr7xfR/m2vQdqHnC@mBistjt@O8Y52szgWjFITQlI6XT2J243Z9DA2b3guNPCP4P)

Returns "LR" for yes and "XeR" for no. Previous version didn't work for inputs like `1,1,111,` so a few bytes went into fixing that.

## Explanation

```
=R       - Right edge
1,R=<,R  - Spawn a triangle and decrement the last number
1<=<1    - Triangle passes trough the last element
,<=*,    - Triangle turns into star after last element
,*=*,    - Star passes trough commas
1*=i     - Reversibly "Decrement" the  element (i=0)
i*=*i    - Star passes trough zeros
,,R=t,R  - When done, send a test probe (t)
it=t1    - Test probe passes trough zeros, turning them to ones
,t=T,    - Upgrade test probe
iT=T1    - Still passes trough zeros
1,T=1,   - And when done, delete itself
T=L      - Or, if the left edge was reached, turn into L
L1=L     - L deletes everything to it's right
L,=L     - --||--
LR       - And finally, success
*=Xe     - Or, if the star reached the end, create error
1t=e     - Or if there weren't enough elements to delete last time, create error (b>c)
1T=e     - Same as before (a+b>c)
i,T=e    - Too many elements to delete (a+b<c) 
1e=e     - Errors propagate
ie=e     - --||--
ei=e     - --||--
e1=e     - --||--
e,=e     - --||--
,e=e     - --||--
e=Xe     - Unify error types
XeR      - Final error state
```

## Example run:

```
1,1,11,
1,1,11,R
1,1,1<,R
1,1,<1,R
1,1*,1,R
1,i,1,R
1,i,<,R
1,i*,,R
1,*i,,R
1*,i,,R
i,i,,R
i,it,R
i,t1,R
iT,1,R
T1,1,R
L1,1,R
L,1,R
L1,R
L,R
LR
```

## Example run 2

```
1,1,111,
1,1,111,R
1,1,11<,R
1,1,1<1,R
1,1,<11,R
1,1*,11,R
1,i,11,R
1,i,1<,R
1,i,<1,R
1,i*,1,R
1,*i,1,R
1*,i,1,R
i,i,1,R
i,i,<,R
i,i*,R
i,*i,R
i*,i,R
*i,i,R
Xe,i,R
Xei,R
Xe,R
XeR
```

Comment: give this man a bounty for using the new lang "Shue"!

Comment: I'm trying to run this with an input of `1,1,11,` on my local machine, since it times out on TIO, and it's taking a *very* long time. How long did it take for `1,1,111,` when you ran it?

Comment: @DLosc whoops, I forgot to add an error propagation rule, fixed now. The link contains an optimized version, which doesn't consider strings that have more than one "R". It can now run `1,1,111,` and others in TIO.

Comment: Ah, nice. I think another approach, which isn't quite as fast but doesn't require changing the interpreter, is to change the first line from `=R` to `1,=<,R`.

Answer (score 8):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>46</s> <s>41</s> <s>42</s> 38 bytes

*Edit: Bug-fix for +1 byte thanks to pajonk, but then -4 bytes by adopting [Giuseppe's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242967/95126) use of `head` with a negative `n`...*

```r
function(x)any(diff(x)[-1]-head(x,-2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY7LCsIwEEX3/YosE0igk0e1C79ERGrbYFBSkAr16@ONbiqxMAwD9zHnkeI0n3243MNtPCT/jP0cpsgX0cUXH4L3OI@KTuo6dgNfpNJCrDO85yQZRktmJHNCVL9qI1kLg4PDFqKFtMt5XWO1uAxhuVoXVpRbmGEjaFWBgP9l/xrNblQCcA/Gf2oG1194Q9txyvBNSWU@fyGkNw)

Function `not_fiblike` outputs `TRUE` if the input `x` is *not* a fibonacci-like sequence, `FALSE` if it is one.

Comment: [40 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242967/67312) :-)

Comment: Looks like it fails for `c(3, 3, 6)`; if I understand correctly `!` in `seq` should fix it for +1: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY7LCsIwEEX3/Yq4y0AKzaPVLvolpYjWBoKSolZIvr7e6qaSCmEInDt3zmP243S07nxz16GZ7cv3kxs9DyI2F2ctD9TmsqOTjzzmoX0Od76L1NF6j/dcCoanBNOClUTZL60EqxEokTAJNED7ZV8VGDV@WmKUhUqiKDcIIybBskQB99P@tZr5UwnBAxy36CKuvvJ646r@9FZE8xs "R – Try It Online")

Answer (score 8):

## [Wolfram Mathematica](https://wolfram.com/mathematica) <s>34</s> 29 bytes

```
 2#~Drop~2==MovingMap[Tr,#,2]&
```

–5 bytes from @att

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU09C4MwEN39FYGA05WaS7R1sDh0FTp0E4dQauvgByJdgv719A6lUjiOex/3Xmun97O1U/Owvs48yuU69sOCWVb0n6Z7FXYo7yNIwCr0t7HpplIeLnUuq/CYu8ApEDQIQoOIZwhcAiIlLibSMDaETuzCiFZKl1a04ghZpS9DOimK4RpltvMXbHYrxZ@pYSO4Cdc2rf5MituSPYiz5mD2Xw)

[Included the `[3,4,6,10,16]` and `[1,1,1,2]` falsey test cases from Noodle9 and DLosc, respectively.]

Comment: [29 bytes](https://tio.run/##VU09C4MwEN39FYGA05WaM9o6pDh0FTp0E4dQas3gB0G6BP3r6QWlpXAc9z7uvV7P3bPXs3lo3yqPfL3acVpRqWp8m@FV6am@W@CATexv1gxzzQ@XtuRNfCxd5AQwGgSWAssWiFwOrCAuI1IGLAmdggsTWgVdqaCVJRhU@pKkkyIC3KLkfn6D5c9K8Wdq2InQhFtbKv5MIrTlS7T4Dw)

Comment: Nice trick using the doubled sequence :)

Answer (score 7):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 31 bytes

```
def f(a,*d):a+d[0]-d[1]or f(*d)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TZBNDoIwEIX3nGKWoCWhUBRw7wncERaNtJHEAMGSyFncsNFreA4TD-Pjz5A0kzff_LxMH6-6M5eq7Ptna7QbvXOlSduSbXInkds89TI3T3lWNaBgU9fnqwEkFSWlFqWcEZ7PKGAUZgxkxygGDEHFCATS_dDnewgxVMARQs8fyxgUaECJj_m8bqXFov9OYjUJvwiWCxm8_ck_GBZmiUWm6RKcIJ1D3RSlsY_yelOORep-VrVJJnhqWjXfuPzIDw)

-3 bytes thanks to @emanresuA.

Outputs via presence of an exception or not.

Comment: [Save three more bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TZBNDoIwEIX3nGKWoCWhUBRw7wncERaNtJHEAMGSyFncsNFreA4TD-Pjz5A0kzff_LxMH6-6M5eq7Ptna7QbvXOlSduSbXInkds89TI3T3lWNaBgU9fnqwEkFSWlFqWcEZ7PKGAUZgxkxygGDEHFCATS_dDnewgxVMARQs8fyxgUaECJj_m8bqXFov9OYjUJvwiWCxm8_ck_GBZmiUWm6RKcIJ1D3RSlsY_yelOORep-VrVJJnhqWjXfuPzIDw) by not using `b` or `c`

Answer (score 7):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>43</s> <s>38</s> 31 bytes

```
#[[;;-3]]+#[[2;;-2]]==#[[3;;]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU1LCoMwFNx7ikDATSM1P1sJFo/QvbyFlEpd6KJkFzx7Og@lpRAe88vMMsbXcxnj/Bjz1GU5DCFUlugEZAANUdcB2xCIynx/z2scZHWbeknluU9F0krgGSWsEn5TRWqUaKF5iI65A7twytQ4LZDVOL427OKXgw9HM92r3AG/xe4XRf0VC4fAS2Zfs/ovpHmt2YotfwA)

Previously I had a 43-byte version using Partition, which simplifies to a 39-byte solution with BlockMap:

```
And@@BlockMap[Plus@@#==2#[[3]]&,#,3,1]&
```

In case it gives anyone ideas, there is a 44-byte solution using a function specifically for generating linear recurrences:

```
#==LinearRecurrence[{1,1},#[[;;2]],Tr[1^#]]&
```

Comment: `==` isn't `Listable`, so you don't need `And@@`

Comment: Also, `BlockMap` is shorthand for mapping over `Partition`

Comment: @att Thanks for the tips

Comment: There's also this 37 byte one that's nearly competitive: `{-1,1,1}~ListConvolve~#~MatchQ~{0..}&`

Comment: Better, `0==##&@@...` for 32

Comment: `Rest@Differences@#==#~Drop~-2&` for 30 bytes (or `Rest@Differences@#==#[[;;-3]]&`)

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 4 bytes

```
IḊw@
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700KzUnp3LBgqWlJWm6Fss8H-7oKndYUpyUXAwV2hitFG2so2Cio2Cuo2BoFKsUC5UAAA)

```
I      differences between consecutive elements
 Ḋ     remove the first item
  w@   find the sublist index of this in the input
```

`1` is truthy and all other values are falsey.

Comment: `IḊẇ` - 3 bytes, uses 1/0 for truthy/falsey

Comment: The shortening to 3 bytes doesn't work for sequences like 1, 3, 6, 12, 24, ...

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 40 bytes

```r
function(l)any(diff(l,2)-head(l,-1)[-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxBCsIwFET3PYXL/2ECnZ9GCXgTcVFag4USQXTh6WOCZjePmXnPkg5nV9I7L6/tkWXXOX9k3VKSHabufpvXmhz14njVkmQRgjB4BNWh8RERDLDpz1PEqW5sBCPhSYTRajf8zoY@7KLOvomsuTxVyxc)

Returns `FALSE` for Fibonacci-like sequences, and `TRUE` otherwise.

Slightly different approach than [Dominic van Essen's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242953/67312), takes the lag-2 differences of `l` and compares to the list with the first and last elements removed, relying on  the following idea:

\$F_{n+1}=F_{n}+F_{n-1}\Rightarrow F_n=F_{n+1}-F_{n-1}\$

Comment: I love the use of the ```lag``` parameter for ```diff```, that I'd never previously seen a use for!  But I'm afraid I've stolen your use of a negative ```n``` for head...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen you have to know your [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138046/67312)!

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 32 bytes

- -1 byte by [l4m2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76323/l4m2)

```javascript
a=>!a.some(n=>n+a[i]-a[++i],i=1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY/LCsIwEEX3fkXcNTQtzaNqF@mPhC5CbSXSJmLF3483FFxIhGEYOIeZO3f7ttv4dI9X5cN1irOOVvdHW29hnQqve19a44bKmrJ0A3Oa0zgGv4VlqpdwK@bCcEZQghHJSDtQevjhJ0Y6KC0clcEK8Jx2iAatwyQ5WtuIjIwTCjpEnqF7DJUn34zq714kvSBsnqcfxP6HTMfjBw)

Comment: [32](https://tio.run/##dY/LCsIwEEX3fkXcNTQtzaNqF@mPhC5CbSXSJmLF3483FFxIhGEYOIeZO3f7ttv4dI9X5cN1irOOVvdHW29hnQqve19a44bKmrJ0A3Oa0zgGv4VlqpdwK@bCcEZQghHJSDtQevjhJ0Y6KC0clcEK8Jx2iAatwyQ5WtuIjIwTCjpEnqF7DJUn34zq714kvSBsnqcfxP6HTMfjBw)

Answer (score 5):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 27 bytes

```
a->#Pol(Ser(a)*(1-x-x^2))<3
```

A sequence is Fibonacci-like if and only if its generating function is of the form \$\frac{a+b\ x}{1-x-x^2}\$.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU1LCsIwFLzKo24SSaD5VC1ozyC4LBGysFIoNQQX9fRxHi0K4TG/zKSYR/1MZaBLibrbXV@TuD2yiHIvjF70crdSnl2JKU0fEUl3lPI4vwErJhUNyEpFfW8U4VlFTlEToBwUtdAaiJ65BztyytY4LZAzOE1t2cUvDx@OYbpW@Q3@iv0/ivoTFjaBl@y65kwIsnwB)

Answer (score 5):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org/), <s>48</s> <s>44</s> 43 bytes

```
~f=0∉3:length(f).|>i->f[i]==f[i-2]+f[i-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY1NCsIwFIT3OUWWLabS/FStkF4kZOHCp5FSRCK4kK71ml4kTihChPCSmbxv5nIfw0E@UprJtp/XW@/H43SK54rq9XMIzUAueGsxG@VX@ZI@RWmdFBxHCa4F7zyLyrqN4D3cDraBo60z0Nu8qVqMHi8tMbpW4d9YB9ZgA3/SM0ZLLDKBk/rvyJb@EWjaoQzWEpJr1VKtc9L1FqY4TtUcZV0IVQpdClOzgqKSopKikiJQ6Qs)

Comment: please use `all` instead of `!(0 in(`, it hurts my eyes

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that function.

Comment: Please use `0∉` instead of `all`, it hurts my eyes (`~f=0∉3:length(f).|>i->f[i]==f[i-2]+f[i-1]`)

Comment: @dingledooper I'm wondering the whole time if there is a clever way to get rid of the `length` statement. This is costly and I needed a in most challenges so far.

Comment: This gets you to 29: `~f=diff(f)[2:end]==f[1:end-2]`. The slicing part is annoyingly verbose and it could probably be improved, but it's a lot better than the "long way".

Comment: @dingledooper turn it into an answer and I'll upvote it!

Comment: Yep @dingledooper I scrolled down thinking about a `diff` solution, then saw you've posted a good one already. Worth turning into an answer.

Comment: @dingledooper although your solution with `diff` is better, `all` is shorter than `∉` (don't need the `.|>`) [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY1BCwIhFITv@ys8rmSwPt1qA/sj4mEPvTJkiTDotH/dRpbAQJ7O@L6ZxzvFWX9KWdnNKfVxf2Efg3OYewq7eumgzDldl1u@9yxlydp5rQQOKWGUGEOXyfmDEhPcEbaFY5y30Me6SQPGhJfRGONA@LfOg7XYwJ8OXcdbLDKBM/13VMv8CDSdUAZrC6m1tFWbmvR8xSWnpV@zlo2gVphWWNk1FLcUtxS3FIMqXw "Julia 1.0 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 34 bytes

```hs
g(a:l@(b:c:_))=a+b==c&&g l;g _=0<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY7PCoJAEIfvPsUgIUp7cP9oaS106gm6hchqsUqbhdqhp99GosgsWIad/X4z@1WqOx2NsVb7KjUbv0jLNA8CqeaFlKXnaTArDbkM19SeVd2AhMPFgWtbNz24u/bWV3f31c9Aw54SwMMIcAJRNkIxgQRphFiMicD3xTDJQiwJ3jjFEoVsnMOdApOYoZnz1tgq000tUOHrl0818WsxCi7RcYIGa/Y05/TPIB3M48w@AA)

- Thanks to @Laikoni for suggesting a recursive approach 1 Byte shorter
- Original solution 35 bytes

```hs
g l@(a:b:c)=zipWith(-)c l==b:init c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY7RCoIwFIbvfYqDdKGwwM2pKQy66gmCLsKLaeFGy0TXRb38OhJFZsE47Oz7z9mn5HA6GuNcA2YdyKIq6lDcdbfTVgXLsAYjRFXoVluo3VnqFgQcLh50vW4t@Nv@atXNf/ULaGBPCeBhBGICSTlBKYEcaYKYTwnH92ycZBGWHG8xxZJEbJrDnRyTmKGl99bYSDPMLVDh65dPNf5rMQqu0HGGRmv2NI/pn0E6mqelewA)

Comment: The simple recursive approach is one byte shorter: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY7PCoJAEIfvPsUgIUp7cP9oaS106gm6hchqsUqbhdqhp99GosgsWIad/X4z@1WqOx2NsVb7KjUbv0jLNA8CqeaFlKXnaTArDbkM19SeVd2AhMPFgWtbNz24u/bWV3f31c9Aw54SwMMIcAJRNkIxgQRphFiMicD3xTDJQiwJ3jjFEoVsnMOdApOYoZnz1tgq000tUOHrl0818WsxCi7RcYIGa/Y05/TPIB3M48w@AA "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 5):

## [Dyalog APL](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
⊃2∘↓⍷2+/⊢
```

-1 thanks to @DLosc.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pcw9CsJAEMXxq7xyBwlmZj/iHmeJKMKCQiprIUhAEGysrbyBvUeZi8RdRLsHP94/HXKzPqa83zZ9TsOw6@d5o@NVp5Po@a7jTS8vWSx1ehR4Pw2DIbDwZAIi2EMcGRfRFZEWHBmWGb4VMhYOHZjJ1JOj/9t9LWCFWGcJSW1Z/gGXVKAP)

Taking the array `1 1 2 3 5` as an example:

```
 2∘↓      Is the array with the first two elements removed         (2 3 5)
    ⍷     a subarray of
     2+/⊢ the sum of each consecutive pair of numbers in the array (2 3 5 8)
⊃         at the first position?
```

Comment: Thanks! Just updated my answer.

Answer (score 5):

## [Curry (PAKCS)](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/%7Epakcs/), 22 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to [Wheat Wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/wheat-wizard).

```
f(_++a:b:c:_)|a+b/=c=0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4tKqrULUjMTi7@/z9NI15bO9EqySrZKl6zJlE7Sd822dbgf25iZp6CrUKaQrShjgIQGekoGOsomMT@BwA)

This returns nothing if the input is Fibonacci-like, and `0` otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 39 bytes

- -3 bytes by [loopy walt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/107561/loopy-walt)

```python
lambda a:map(sum,zip(a[1:-1],a))==a[2:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7dCsIwDIXvfYpethBh/VNX6JPUXkRkOLCz6LzQl68pg0GHEEI45yT58me@PSZVBn8ud0yXKzJ0CTN/vRN8x8wxSLeXEVAI7zEoF0t@jtPMBx4kMCoFTAOzUYjd6hyA9WRack1jGJKPdU911HqatKRmO9XE6KChIEVkoy/vzFZbKcyfK8RyIpytU/nUwqjrk/ID)

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) + [NumPy](https://numpy.org), 35 bytes

```python
lambda a:all(a[1:-1]+a[:-2]==a[2:])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY/dCsIwDIXvfYpctlhl/Zm6wp6k9iIiw8HWlTov9vQ1c@CVFUII5EvOOXGZH1PQuWuvecDxdkdAi8PA0El7kH6Pzh6Ub1t0ynqe@zFOaYbwGuMC@IQQdzH1YWYdC/GIKeHCnBRApQRoAbXnnP9gTgIawmriTAExBJzXX6qi1tCkJbW6UoUDkjN0QrAsEJstU95@fZu/GuT@QgHKzJpNbfn0x0x@Aw)

Comment: [-3](https://tio.run/##bY7dCsIwDIXvfYpethBh/VNX6JPUXkRkOLCz6LzQl68pg0GHEEI45yT58me@PSZVBn8ud0yXKzJ0CTN/vRN8x8wxSLeXEVAI7zEoF0t@jtPMBx4kMCoFTAOzUYjd6hyA9WRack1jGJKPdU911HqatKRmO9XE6KChIEVkoy/vzFZbKcyfK8RyIpytU/nUwqjrk/ID)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
¥¦Å?
```

Port of [*@pxeger*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242936/52210).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0NJDyw632v//H21iqWNuqGNoZKBjaGmoY2xoqGNqYBQLAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXL/0NLDy073Gr/X@d/dLShjqGOkY6xjmmsTrSZjqWOoamOkQmQbWKpYw6UMzLQMbQ01DE2NNQxNTACihvrmOiY6xgaApkgjSZgGmKECVTaTMdCxxLMBhpnBDLR2DA2FgA).

An inversed version is also possible, but would be a [byte](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) longer:

```
ü+¨Å¿
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8B7tQysOtx7a//9/tImljrmhjqGRgY6hpaGOsaGhjqmBUSwA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXL/8N7tA@tONx6aP9/nf/R0YY6hjpGOsY6prE60WY6ljqGpjpGJkC2iaWOOVDOyEDH0NJQx9jQUMfUwAgobqxjomOuY2gIZII0moBpiBEmUGkzHQsdSzAbaJwRyERjw9hYAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
       #  e.g. input = [49,71,120,191,311,502]

¥      # Get the deltas/forward-differences of the (implicit) input-list
       #  STACK: [22,49,71,120,191]
 ¦     # Remove the first item
       #  STACK: [49,71,120,191]
  Å?   # Check if the (implicit) input-list starts with this sublist
       #  STACK: 1
       # (after which the result is output implicitly)

ü      # For each overlapping pair of the (implicit) input-list:
 +     #  Add them together
       #   STACK: [120,191,311,502,813]
  ¨    # Remove the last item
       #   STACK: [120,191,311,502]
   Å¿  # Check if the (implicit) input-list ends with this sublist
       #   STACK: 1
       # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 4):

## 80386 machine code, <s>19</s> 16 bytes

```
\x49\x49\x8b\x44\x8a\x04\x2b\x04\x8a\x2b\x44\x8a\xfc\xe1\xf3\xc3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVHtasIwFP3dPMUlMki26vrl15xj77FKSdNUA7UdbRxF8dXX3VgZIrpBmntucnrOuUQO11J2A13KYpcpeG1MpqvR5q1LEmFMrdOdUUnCWKOk0VXJ6Mio1lDOOciNqCHV5ccKloTGbTTvv1mKNcIq4tbDGqR9tX1wcZfLuFU@1jBuZUgX15a5aIwURYFWjRFGS9ClAaMak@uUWSzd09Gj4HAgjoX1gjgo02yTBL6qAv8qFDDiONQq2bT0xXbLdyn3FFjNXds@ScTyjDPEghOHo1atzK4ureyRkEGmcl0q@KzRirW8BzmjD1lcUvc3WqP3qsot4RkiF1rOCbHhtkKX7BS1V2CnIT5W/OC7gCtwIXRhfOTW@ZoycWGOrDHSotuMCO@nVinwcJsjCn3cxl5wm49emG6KXP9EuBkLM92xu8wc/eWAyWcY/i7FjhX0o4X@P0K@HW3Sk85v49m36bpvmRdi3XTDbRj8AA)

Applying @PeterCordes's suggestion to remove `setz` saved 3 bytes. I first considered simply returning `al` as a boolean value, but then the problem is that a non-zero value will represent `false` and zero will represent `true`. I felt it's not clear-cut whether this is okay.

Now, the function works as returning the zero flag. Thus, it is not possible to be directly called from C as before. If you follow the TIO link, there is a wrapper function to interface with this assembly function returning a flag value. Since I'll usually have to write such wrapper when calling functions from other languages, I think this approach is okay.

Thanks to @Deadcode for letting me know a nice way to translate the flag to a value in the wrapper function.

**assembly (nasm)**

```
testfib: ; fastcall, ecx = length of array, edx = pointer to array
    dec ecx
    dec ecx
.loop:
    mov eax, [edx + ecx * 4 + 4]
    sub eax, [edx + ecx * 4]
    sub eax, [edx + ecx * 4 - 4]
    loopz .loop
    ret
```

Comment: You can return in ZF if you want, avoiding the `setz`: [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165020).  The language of your answer is pure asm / machine code, not including C calling conventions.  Also, EAX will already be zero or non-zero after `sub` to match ZF, so you can call that the integer return value.  (0 or non-zero are equally easy to test for a caller, so [both are valid choices for "truthy" in asm](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/interpretation-of-truthy-falsey/7074#7074).)

Comment: Anyway, interesting approach; I was thinking of loading the first 2 and then computing *forward* (with `xchg`/`add` or `xadd` as in [Golf a Custom Fibonacci Sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211331)) and compare against memory.  And take a pointer in `esi` for `lodsd` / `xchg eax, edx` / `lodsd`.  Possibly take an end-pointer instead of a count, for looping with `cmp`/`jne`?  But then you'd need some other way to break out of the loop, like possibly `scasd`/`jne` as well.  Your idea to use `loopz` is nice.

Comment: Can you post an objdump to show how the bytes map to instructions? I guess the mov instructions look pretty complicated. ecx is changing from loopz?

Comment: @qwr [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/bMfbqdG6f). Yes, `loopz` decrements `ecx`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I applied your suggestion. BTW, is that second link correct? I think that post is suggesting that only `1` can represent "true" for functions returning an integer value.

Comment: I linked the wrong part of that Q&A (some random answer that came up in a search); meant to link a comment about languages like asm that don't have `if(x)`, just jump-if-zero and jump-if-nonzero: [Interpretation of Truthy/Falsey](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/9441).  Also [another comment](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/interpretation-of-truthy-falsey/2194#comment9435_2191) on the same Q&A.

Comment: [Called from C.](https://tio.run/##hVHtSsMwFP3dPMUlIiTazX5tOr/wDXyAVUqaplugS6XNpGz46tabdsgYUyHJPUlOzjmXyMlKyv5CG1ltCwWPrS10PV0/91kmrG10vrUqyxhrlbS6NoxOreos5ZyDXIsGcm2Wb/BEaNoli3He5VgTrCLtAqxRPla3j47uSpl2KsQap52M6cOpZSlaK0VVoVVrhdUStLFgVWtLnTOHpT8cXQkOe@I52DwQD2XaTZbBR13hq0oBI55HnZJLm5rU0nt38vQi5Y4Ca7jvttcSsTzgArHgxOOo1yi7bYyT/iTkolClNgreG7RjHR9ByehlkRrq/8Rr9U7VpSPcQOJDxzkhLuBGaMOGuKMCGxpZvvF96AOOyIfYh9knd86nlLkPC2TNkJacZyR4f@uUogCXBaI4xGUWROf56IXpbpEbDoSzsTDTL3bHmZO/HDD5HYb/leLaisbW4vAfodC1Nh9Jh78J3N/0/ZcsK7Fq@8kmjvrJa/wN) https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#FlagOutputOperands

Comment: @Deadcode That's cool! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>5</s> <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
€¹tẊ-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8f@jpjWHdpY83NWl@////@hoE0sdc0MdQyMDHUNLQx1jQ0MdUwOjWJ1oEwvs4oY6RjomsbEA)

Outputs `1` for truthy (it's a fibonacci-like sequence), any other non-negative integer for falsy (it isn't a fibonacci-like sequence).

Get the pairwise differences (`Ẋ-`), remove the first one (`t`), and <s>check if this is an ordered sublist of the input</s> find the index of this sublist in the input (`€ḣ¹`), or `0` if not present.

<s>Of course, it needs to be a *prefix* of the input (rather than a sublist at any other position), but I think this should be ensured since the input is increasing.</s>
*Edit:* the fact that the input is increasing does *not* ensure that sublists must be prefixes (consider `1 2 4` with difference sublist `2`), so we check this by requiring that the index of the sublist must be `1`.

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 10 bytes

```
d4L)tfGw)=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3BCsIwEETvfsVcC0GTzabaQ/Ei2IN48lBaAgoiCHor1L@PEwNFCMvOzObN@za90vWJvsNwxh5rRHRIdz1V0@M4V23qDxg@uMQ0OgM@MfAGIa7G2qChFegppVJs841YjoabdxzBCkN@UcYMHFXBaNkWpi53JO8ILzp3SOnx7v/E5Z6ajvwIhWg39gs)

Just the usual: take the pairwise difference, discard the first, chop off the last two elements of input, compare.

---

*Alternate*:

#### [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
tnwTTZ+2YSG=s-I<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY0xC8IwFIR3f8XtRk1ekmpBcRGsi4sZakpAR0FdLOi/j1cDRQiPd3cv3z2u/T1fbmgbxCO2mCOhQe6f7xDiVM6n/eY1O6xzu0P8IKTcGQU@UbAKPk26SqGm5ek5SkexHG5Ec9TcrOHwWhjyi2PMwFAVjCvbyHTjHckrwoseOqT0WPN/Yoaeio78CIWoF/oL)

Perform a convolution of the input with `[1 1]`, circularly shift the result twice to align the sums, compare with input, and see that the last `n - 2` values match. (The last two bytes might as well be `2=` I think, but it's the same byte count anyway.)

Previous solution: `TT2&Y+3L)G&m2-tf=`
Perform a convolution of the input with `[1 1]`, and check that the 1:n-1 values of the result (excluding the last sum) are present in the input at right index.

---

Output is all 1s (in both solutions) for truthy.

Answer (score 3):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 37 bytes

```
f(l)=min(1-sign(l[3...]-l[2...]-l)^2)
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gc4zlbve6p)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2xdy0dyg2c)

Tell me if there is anything wrong. I made this answer faster than usual :D

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 46 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n[2:]and(n[0]+n[1]-n[2]or f(n[1:]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7NCsIwEITveYo9Nhih@am2BZ8k7KFSgoW6ltKLTx8nKqgIYcl8k8zsct8uN/HtsuacTvNwPY8DSS/R9TzIWEmseSfR8h6IbyslINuz1jlBzTQJxWgN4ThD3lDDRsWDoQ6sAQxFB6hjeeVqjA43bzGa2hUXvwJ8OJa5V7Ssk2xVqmatlfqtQccz8LsxfDLQ26L6DcoK7rWG/0vODw)

Recursion is shorter than doing `all(... for i,e in enumerate(n))`.

-2 by @emanresuA, -4 by @pxeger. What am I doing today...

Comment: [Saved some bytes](https://tio.run/##ZY7NCsIwEITveYo9thih@am2AZ8k7KGiwUJMS@3Fp48TFVSEsGRmkvl2vq@XKZluXnIOhzhcj6eBkku@4U3yirfJa54WChWU43oMBMfxOd7OnnNAFGlM5L2ShKMlGUktS@F3knp4LUxbtIXal1e6wehxMwqjbXRJ8csiR6KYnaB5GdNahSrWtRC/GDCehd9E@@kAtwP6bZQV9GsN89ecHw)

Comment: saved some more bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7NCsIwEITveYo9Nhih@am2BZ8k7KFSgoW6ltKLTx8nKqgIYcl8k8zsct8uN/HtsuacTvNwPY8DSS/R9TzIWEmseSfR8h6IbyslINuz1jlBzTQJxWgN4ThD3lDDRsWDoQ6sAQxFB6hjeeVqjA43bzGa2hUXvwJ8OJa5V7Ssk2xVqmatlfqtQccz8LsxfDLQ26L6DcoK7rWG/0vODw "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 30 bytes

```
[ dup differences rest head? ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY6/DoIwEId3nuL3BIaWAqKDo3FxMU7GoYEjEAVrewyG8OxYgkG9m@67P9@VOueHHc@nw3G/QaO5WjnWXDuuc4cb2ZbucPTsqM3JwVhifhlbt4xtEPQBfPQQPiUixBg@JEEGEUOqhagMqZ@TIUQmEAmBOJRLN4JCCg@H5aSE@qlmgfpbSLD2mi/xSjlZo@nMEIwXFJ1BUZcl2fl/S45RkS52uI6NNliNbw)

### Explanation

Does the input start with its differences sans the first?

```
              ! { 1 1 2 3 5 }
dup           ! { 1 1 2 3 5 } { 1 1 2 3 5 }
differences   ! { 1 1 2 3 5 } { 0 1 1 2 }
rest          ! { 1 1 2 3 5 } { 1 1 2 }
head?         ! t
```

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>58</s> <s>57</s></sup> 51 bytes

```c
r;f(a,n)int*a;{for(r=0;n-->2;)r|=*a+*++a-a[1];n=r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZPbjpswEIbv9ymmSJE4GBXMKanL9qLqUyRcIGK2qK2zwkiNmubVSwcGiL2LHA/m@z3zewJN@NI049iL1q2Z8jo1@LW4tZfe7ctIqDB85sLr/5Z@HfhBUIf1Ma6EKntxH1ELv@pOuR7cngCv6cEg9RAfKyjhFjPAwRkkDLK72DAnnDM4oCJDSWrQhGiKrJgy8AinA94lMU5ZxA1tSlrMn6IadbEBs80FWjAr5O/tmbgwk6LJeDKQG4L9Jpj8czpDgqXXJvizTJNsbgijg1NIKKQUMgo5hYLC/pFsXivKpbs/8tK6c0rv47LyacnAoNym3KaJTRObpjZNbZrZNLNpbtPcpoVNC5vubbr3jB7I66tsBnk2/zka0TYWeXNReoDme937OMvmh@xpl3O6fuOn6@Er/jKHgblOnGU3vvjgThU7dZZX3BaJ5fbz6nX18rC7PREQBLPam5PRV/F4KTAdvRizphImBrVQ9Y4@PC1@0IuaS3mbZrpeexS1rrPTuzOer/syHfKTc8QwHLvKs@tpTPYBO48fvQ0kgq3fb72sNSoIn2F3hp0@Kcyv2dZrXZZyrXV/uo//mvZn/aLH8Pd/)

*Saved 6 bytes thanks to [pxeger](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/97857/pxeger)!!!*

Inputs a pointer to an array on integers and its length (because pointers in C carry no length info).
Returns \$0\$ if its a Fibonacci-like sequence or a truthy value otherwise.

Comment: 51 bytes: `r;f(a,n)int*a;{for(r=0;n-->2;)r|=*a+*++a-a[1];n=r;}`

Comment: @pxeger Nice one - thanks! :)))

Comment: @pxeger: Just for the record, `*a` and `a[1]` are [unsequenced](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order) wrt. `*++a` in that, so it's perhaps worth mentioning that reliance on this happens-to-work implementation detail of how GCC -O0 handles this undefined behaviour.  (Beyond the usual nasty hacktastic return value via a `gcc -O0` implementation detail mentioned in the C golfing tips Q&A.)  Still a valid code golf answer, just worth mentioning this abuse of C to get the compiler to make working asm.

Comment: @PeterCordes I actually tried `*a+++*a-a[1]` at first, which didn't work! So yes, I'm aware ;)

Comment: @PeterCordes Avert thine eye, code golfing is not for the pure of heart! Lots of terrible hacks here that rely solely on specific flags and the direction of the wind! T_T

Comment: I didn't say it was a bad thing for code golf, just that it's interesting to distinguish between C vs. UB implementation detail.  e.g. mention which order of evaluation and side-effects this relies on somewhere in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

## [C (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org), 44 bytes

```
f(a,n)int*a;{n=*a+*++a-a[1]||--n>2&&f(a,n);}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XZBRSsQwEIbf9xQx4pJpk7pJ09W1rN5hX2uRUBMpaJRtFsHunsSXfVnv5DU8gRMaEIQwzPzzzzdMPk_dw1PXfTVUvNP2eNoFJ66_uWOGe-h9yEw9-nVm8izPjTCNbPd7Ifytms8nT31IMz_nj9b13pINM0VRwIjTJDTtejSH-m2LlWP0Yrj3lJ85FvjQf9hXTOAyZegAuKNhu7P0hjrzPFiK-NmL6T2DcbZhkhN8ipOSkwpQWHKyQq1CUcdaY3UVXWqBYYVZKTFUCxW7OKWxjx0JEw1RGv6B9Z8V8TKClkmKu9S0r0REuvyYfu0X)

-1 byte by inverting output, thanks to @AZTECCO

Recursive.

Comment: misread that title as "CGCC"

Answer (score 3):

## [Standard ML (MLton)](http://www.mlton.org/), <s>51</s> <s>48</s> 45 bytes

```ml
fun$(x::y::z::L)=x+y=z andalso$(tl L)| $_=1=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87N0c3NKcnP@/8/rTRPRaPCyqrSyqrKyspH07ZCu9K2SiExLyUxpzhfRaMkR8FHs0ZBJd7W0Nbwf1lijkJJUWmqgq2CikK0mY6CpY6CoamOgpFJLBdILg2oCSpprKNgoqMAVGJoAMRmsf8B)

-3 bytes thanks to Laikoni.

-3 bytes using `tl` to recurse instead of pattern matching.

Comment: Save two bytes by replacing `f` with a symbol, e.g. `$`, and another byte by replacing `true` with `1=1`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87N0c3NKcnP@/8/rTRPRaPCyqrSyqrKyspH07ZCu9K2SiExLyUxpzhfRQMmXqOgEm9raGv4vywxR6GkqDRVwVYhTSHaTEfBUkfB0FRHwcgklgsklwbUB5U01lEw0VEAKjE0AGKz2P8A "Standard ML (MLton) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup><s>38</s></sup> 12 bytes

```
2{]E.~2+/\}:
```

Or

```
2&}.-:2+/\}:
```

-26 bytes, thanks @Jonah

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/japjXfXqjLT1Y2qt/mtypSZn5CukKZhYKpgbKhgaGSgYWhoqGBsaKpgaGMEkjRVMFMwVDA0RfEugUgVDU6BCmBhQs4IRSOV/AA)

Comment: APL answers approach for 14: `2(1{.}.E.+/\)]`

Comment: Actually, 12: `2{]E.~2+/\}:`.  Another variation: `2&}.-:2+/\}:`

Answer (score 3):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/index.html), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
+´↑∊·2⊸↓⊸⋈⊢-»
```

[Try it at BQN online REPL](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RmlibGlrZSDihpAgK8K04oaR4oiKwrcy4oq44oaT4oq44ouI4oqiLcK7CgpGaWJsaWtlwqgg4p+oMeKAvzHigL8y4oC/M+KAvzXigL844oC/MTMsMeKAvzHigL8y4oC/M+KAvzXigL844oC/MTTin6kK)

```
              »     # shift the input array right,
             -      # and subtract this from
            ⊢       # the input;
     ·2⊸↓           # now drop the first two elements,
          ⊸⋈       # and make a list of this list,
    ∊               # and check whether this equals
   ↑                # any prefix of the input;
×´                  # finally get the product to check if all are true.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>38</s> 37 bytes

```
\d+
$*
^((1+),(?=(1+),\2\3\b))+1+,1+$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYyxDsIwEEP3@44iJZyH@i5pyVB15CciBAgGFgbE/4e0EpMtW@99nt/X@9YO4Xxt9aEyHOUSAjUirMue1arXe4xKBXVojSAMjiwTCphhSVLB3HcbwUI4iTyaOBJmkLIBSf5g2o8JJ5TeusI2i/MH) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
^((1+),(?=(1+),\2\3\b))+
```

Repeatedly match a number, each time checking that the number two ahead is the sum of it and the next number.

```
1+,1+$
```

Match the final two numbers.

Previous 38-byte version used .NET's ability to recapture an existing named or numbered group:

```
\d+
$*
^(1+),(1+)(,(?<2>\1(?<1>\2)))+$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYwxCsMwFEP3f44U7FhD9P2d1FDSsZcwpYVmyJKh9P6uXegiCYmn9/bZj2c9udujlleQYZS7Y/Do4uCuF10Lm3Et6r0PQ60EoYhIMiODCWpiGUvrdQIzEUmkSSXCsICUDpj8QfsNM87ILbUL7S@RXw) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
^(1+),(1+)
```

Match two numbers `\1` and `\2`...

```
(,(?<2>\1(?<1>\2)))+$
```

... then repeatedly match numbers that are the sum of `\1` and `\2`, but recapture `\1` as `\2` and `\2` as the sum, so that each number has to be the sum of the previous two.

Answer (score 2):

## APL+WIN, 26 bytes

Prompts for input

```
(¯2+⍴v)=+/(¯2↓v)=1↓-2-/v←⎕
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##RYzNCcJAEIXvU8U7KmFJZnaTuAcLEBRrCJGIEFAIBGwgelEEsQ4vVmAp28g6EcHTfPP@qkNrNseq3W9N3VZdt6tjuD5WyzDcLCkt1kpM4Xxq4uT9lCRcXv10nqTjE4a7MusxYtJek9qImqXYEIMhsMipoQIenEOcsvMo1ZMM7BmWGXkmqls4lGCmsSpw9J9wP7vADP7LOifjouUP)

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 53 bytes

```powershell
!(3..($a=$args).length|?{$a[--$_-2]+$a[$_-1]-$a[$_]})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY9Bb4JAEIXv/IrRbCqku0RAbD2Ykhh7bVN7M8RQOmoNFcsuaRPkt@MABU1LuyGbCe/b994c4k9M5BajSIRxggVbT7OipzumqbNgyoJkIw0zwv1GbY93GQuWQrCVsP1rGmmwfFENfm4UuaZ5ugZ0uKd7usWBPpuDw8E1ODCVpGic9TGHCSEuMaMOeUTiTelhD@ma0ORYdLlDuwOmiBHhBFodal2jClkHkfwhtSU7gdqZut5S3T@Acg27XsWx/jWxyl3GF4gBR7iPk3kQbsXDyw5DBVn1jimUahZIJBa/DiTgK0yBrWo1QZlGin5csTV4DVtpy8fFLJUqfq/9fK82LM8iDUOUkp71eo2FwI9zQkv2n8kSSs9@mdoEgNjFb3sY8EFLzi/K/bJ5amp@p1VCruVacQI)

Takes a list of numbers as parameter and returns a boolean

Comment: -19 bytes. awesome!

Answer (score 2):

## C#, <s>114</s> 113 bytes

```cs
var a=args;int i=0,r=0;for(;i<a.Length-2;)if(int.Parse(a[i])+int.Parse(a[i+1])!=int.Parse(a[i+++2]))r=1;return r;
```

Program expects the list to be passed as a list of command line arguments, e.g.:

```cs
./program 1 2 3 5 8
```

Program uses C# v9 top-level statements feature, this is a full C# program. Unwrapped:

```csharp
var a = args;
int i = 0, r = 0;
for (; i < a.Length - 2;)
    if (int.Parse(a[i]) + int.Parse(a[i + 1]) != int.Parse(a[i++ + 2]))
        r = 1;
return r;
```

Comment: It is permitted to write a function instead of a full program to save a lot of bytes.

Comment: Also a recursive solution may be shorter

Answer (score 2):

## k (ngn/k), 41 bytes

```
c:{~#{x}_*,x{(x@y)=+/x@y-2 1}/:2+!(#x)-2}
```

try it in the [ngn/k repl](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k/#r)

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 44 bytes

inspired by [Julian](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242975/80745)

```powershell
$a,$b,$c=$args
!($c|?{$_-$a-$b;$a,$b=$b,$_})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU7RasJAEHy/r9jKUhO4gInRVkqoIPa1pfpWSojXTa2kRnMJLWi@Pd1LNFrb5TjuZmZnZpN@UaaXlCSOSjOqMA52FUYSFxJVgFH2rsWVhWp/v8PQwcjBxV1NB0YRlnZVCjG2hJAW5llBEtz6eBL6Egb2CR9KGDE1YM4/g30Gb8yO1@NrxK@@y9eg552J2MpnGQvcGo2jRNMxx7@A2vRfRGPBJW65xwVhenlNt77775Jryg1tIWzYw0OaTSO1dB4XK1I57ATwIH1v@EdvElDTtqC1IggAw4bNSBdJzsA1xjA@Cmru5Wk2KXSefjZ@r@PG0MysUIq0Nj4HA4e2p6hW15mTzmESaeoYbZvvrNKPNXRlt1VOD6tG9sfm@VjykFYTpShF9QM)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
¯Ḣ₅⁰Ẏ⁼
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLCr+G4ouKCheKBsOG6juKBvCIsIiIsIls0OSw3MSwxMjAsMTkxLDMxMSw1MDJdIl0=)

*-1 byte thanks to emanresu A*

### How?

```
¯Ḣ₅⁰Ẏ⁼
¯         # Deltas (consecutive differences) of (implicit) input
 Ḣ        # Remove the first item
  ₅       # Push length without popping
   ⁰      # Push the input
    Ẏ     # Slice the input until the length
     ⁼    # Exactly equal to the deltas with first item removed? (non-vectorizing)
```

Comment: `:L` = `₅` for 6 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 18 bytes

```
⬤θ∨‹κ²⁼ι⁺§θ⊖κ§θ⁻κ²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzLCsIwEAB/JcctrNCNihRPBT0Iir2XHkK6YOg20jzEv4@KHpzrDGNvJti7kVK64HyCVgQWVNcAZ44RJlS6QnVcspEIDlUnOUKbTn7k5yc8sA08s088wlS90z93cT7/Fl/2pfT9psEdIekaqSFcE@G21sNQVg95AQ) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs a Charcoal boolean, i.e. `-` for Fibonacci-like, nothing if not. Explanation:

```
 θ                  Input array
⬤                   All elements satisfy
    κ               Current index
   ‹                Is less than
     ²              Literal integer `2`
  ∨                 Logical Or
       ι            Current value
      ⁼             Equals
          θ         Input array
         §          Indexed by
            κ       Current index
           ⊖        Decremented
        ⁺           Plus
              θ     Input array
             §      Indexed by
                κ   Current index
               ⁻    Minus
                 ²  Literal integer `2`
                    Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 35 bytes

```perl
sub{@_-2?$_[1]+shift==$_[1]&&&$f:1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZFba4MwFMff/RSHknlhKRhvW5Wsvg/Wl725IHRLnGxTUQsdpZ/dHZcyqisN4XAuv5xz/qSR7Wc4EMWHbrc9pPnSW5M8Y@K2ey9Vz/lvYJomUTE7Domh6tY2ADLIGAW8HgWfQihgcvgDMBBUgxGFFbIhwsGMm4IBYndjW89Fs0LPZ2hC1xNTECcGiCLE5g2noF7w39QT555zf1pm9ITTg1HQPWq6zo2SPS3bP9/ycj82Ko7EhX7OwRjDr2@blJRIh6ckT04pUnD8GDslpaNTTVtWvVrcLKMOQO4b@drLtxiIxFpR9@gV6JVVs0Mfn71UCwo2lvd1izUH1mA9bZ5h82hBDFb9YSXGcfgB)