# Make the list Fibonacci-like

Tags: code-golf, fibonacci, subsequence

[Related, but not dupe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/242935/108879).

### Challenge

A list of integers \$a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots, a_n\$ (\$ n ≥ 1 \$)  is Fibonacci-like if \$a_i = a_{i-1} + a_{i-2}\$ for every \$i > 2\$. Note that every list that contains only 1 or 2 integers is Fibonacci-like.

For example, \$[1]\$, \$[6, 9]\$, \$[6, -4, 2, -2, 0, -2, -2, -4, -6, -10]\$, \$[7, -1, 6, 5, 11, 16, 27]\$ are Fibonacci-like lists.

Your task is, given a list, to determine the minimum amount of numbers that you have to remove from the list to make it Fibonacci-like.

For example, in \$[9, 7, -1, 6, 5, 2, 11, 16, 27]\$, you have to remove 2 numbers at minimum (\$9\$ and \$2\$) to transform the list into \$[7, -1, 6, 5, 11, 16, 27]\$, which is a Fibonacci-like list.

### Input/Output

Input/output can be taken in any reasonable format, taking a list of numbers and returning the minimum number to complete the task.

Testcases:

```
[1, 2] -> 0
[5, 4, 9, 2] -> 1
[9, 7, -1, 6, 5, 2, 11, 16, 27] -> 2
[9, 9, 9, 9, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, -1, 6, 5, 2, 11, 16, 27] -> 9
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer (in bytes) wins!

Comment: You should include some more challenging test cases with multiple numbers to remove in a row. For example:
[9,9,9,9, 7, 9,9,9,9, -1, 6, 5, 2, 11, 16, 27] => 9

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 63 bytes

```javascript
f=([v,...a],x,y)=>1/v?Math.min(v-x-y?1/0:f(a,y,v),1+f(a,x,y)):0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYxBDoIwFET3nqLLNv4WfqM2kCAn8ASERYOgEGyNkIaevpaNMYaYzGJm/ps/aKen5tU/Z27stQ2hK2jlQAiha1jAs@KMiSsver6LR2@o4wv3JSZp3lENHhwD3K92ZVmehsaayY6tGO2NdrRCILJmbPdTH4EcgGTbx1grIDxOT0AiKYFgDBiTVNv8R@rLZ/@ehDc)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (             // f is a recursive function taking:
  [v,             //   v = next value from the input array
      ...a],      //   a[] = all remaining values
  x,              //   x = penultimate value, initially undefined
  y               //   y = previous value, initially undefined
) =>              //
1 / v ?           // if v is defined:
  Math.min(       //   return the minimum of:
    v - x - y ?   //     1) if both x and y are defined and v is not
                  //        equal to x + y:
      1 / 0       //          force this one to fail by using +infinity
    :             //        else:
      f(a, y, v), //          do a recursive call where v is used
    1 +           //     2) increment the final result
    f(a, x, y)    //        and do a recursive call where v is removed
  )               //   end of Math.min()
:                 // else:
  0               //   stop the recursion
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>90</s> 88 bytes

*Edit: -2 bytes thanks to [@Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe).*

```
\(v)max(which(sapply(sum(v|1):1,\(i)all(combn(v,i,\(x)any(diff(x)[-1]-head(x,-2)))))),0)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RYzBCoJAEIbvPcVAl1mYBXepzKDeoVuQHTZtcUFNMk2hN-liQQ_V2zSp0Fxm_m8-_sfz0r3s-l1drVx-diHWIjMN3hIXJViaokhbLKsM67sSK0UhOmHSFKNzdsyxJsekESZvMXbW8rmX6iCTk4mxIalFP-SJsX9rMUJFwI8pyA14kx-YE8wIgj9WPWbgE0jWFwTsaALFQXHS_mjqobjrhv0F)

Checking Fibonacci-likeness borrowed from [@Dominic van Essen's answer to related challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242953/55372).

Comment: I had started this with using `combn` for index lists but this is much cleaner, and you even remembered to use `FUN` in `combn`!

Comment: maybe use `all` instead of `min` and you can get rid of the `>0`?

Comment: @Giuseppe, yes, you taught me well about the `FUN` in `combn`! And thanks for the golf!

Answer (score 3):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 36 bytes

```
#g-MX#*:S H@>_-_=H H_FIFL*CP:GMZgMlg
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLG51bGwsIiNnLU1YIyo6UyBIQD5fLV89SCBIX0ZJRkwqQ1A6R01aZ01sZyIsIiIsIjYgLTQgMiAtMiAwIC0yIC0yIC00IC02IDEwIiwiLXAiXQ==) -6 thanks to DLosc.

```
#g                                   # Length of input
  -                                  # Minus
   MX                                # Maximum of
     #*:                             # Map length over
                       FL*           # Flatten each of...
                          CP:        # Cartesian product of...
                              MZ     # Map over zipped
                                gMl  # Input filled with empty lists
                                   g # And input...
                             G       # Get all arguments (i.e. both)
                     FI              # Filter by...
        S H                          # Remove first and last items from
              -                      # Differences of 
           @>_ _                     # Shifted value and value
                =                    # Equal to...
                 H H_                # Remove last two items from value?
```

Comment: @DLosc Some of that breaks on [cases containing zeroes](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLG51bGwsIiNnLU1YIyo6UyBIQD5fLV89SCBIX0ZJRkkqQ1A6Z1owWCNnIiwiIiwiNiDiiJI0IDIg4oiSMiAwIOKIkjIg4oiSMiDiiJI0IOKIkjYgMTAiLCIiXQ==) (should be 1)

Comment: Whoops--for some reason, I thought the numbers would always be positive even though that's not even true in the test case... Backing that change out and keeping the others gives [37 bytes](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLG51bGwsIiNnLU1YIyo6UyBIQD5fLV89SCBIX0ZJX1JNbk1DUDpnWm5YI2ciLCIiLCI2IOKIkjQgMiDiiJIyIDAg4oiSMiDiiJIyIOKIkjQg4oiSNiAxMCIsIiJd), but there's something else wrong because that still returns 3, as does your current solution.

Comment: @DLosc That's because I pulled a stupid and pasted unicode hyphens in instead of minuses lol. [This](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLG51bGwsIiNnLU1YIyo6UyBIQD5fLV89SCBIX0ZJX1JNbk1DUDpnWm5YI2ciLCIiLCI2IC00IDIgLTIgMCAtMiAtMiAtNCAtNiAxMCIsIiJd) works, but your [35 still breaks](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLG51bGwsIiNnLU1YIyo6UyBIQD5fLV89SCBIX0ZJRkkqQ1A6Z1owWCNnIiwiIiwiNiAtNCAyIC0yIDAgLTIgLTIgLTQgLTYgMTAiLCIiXQ==)

Comment: It irks me that there doesn't seem to be a short way to get all ordered subsets... I may have to add a builtin. I found a method that's a bit ugly but [saves one byte](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLG51bGwsIiNnLU1YIyo6UyBIQD5fLV89SCBIX0ZJRkwqQ1A6R01aZ01sZyIsIiIsIjYgLTQgMiAtMiAwIC0yIC0yIC00IC02IDEwIiwiLXAiXQ==).

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 19 bytes

```
ẏṗ'?ẏ⊍?$İ₌ÞS¯Ḣc;ÞgL
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLhuo/huZcnP+G6j+KKjT8kxLDigozDnlPCr+G4omM7w55nTCIsIiIsIlsxXSJd)

Long, clunky, and likely to be outgolfed, but it's 1:01am so whatever lol.

Gets all lists of indices where removing the items at those positions gives a Fibonacci list and then gets the length of the smallest indice list.

Comment: There is some kind of bug in it since it returns `0` when given `[1, 3, 6]`.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), <sup><s>31</s></sup> 30 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
≢⌊.-∘∊2(≢⍤⊢×∘⊃↓⍷+/∘,)¨¨(⊢,,¨)\
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=e9S56FFPl57uo44Zjzq6jDQeAfm9Sx51LTo8HSTU1fyobfKj3u3a@kCejuahFYdWaAAldXQOrdCMAQA&f=HYrBFQAQDMXupsgKvygW6np2MJlyy0sSCCtBp7E@LQZnC09nSMixkUFvpaaeFw&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=dfn&n=f)

`(⊢,,¨)\` gets all non-empty subsequences of the input (taken from [Bubbler's tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211449/64121)).

`2(≢⍤⊢×∘⊃↓⍷+/∘,)x` If x is Fibonacci-like, this returns the length of x, otherwise 0.

`≢⌊.-∘∊x` computes the minimum value of `length of input - some number in x`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ŒP+⁼ƭ3\Ạ$ƇṪLạL
```

A monadic Link that accepts the list of integers and yields the count of elements to remove.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATQAy/9qZWxsef//xZJQK@KBvMatM1zhuqAkxofhuapM4bqhTP///1sxLCAzLCA2LCAxMiwgMjRd)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opADtR417jq01jnm4a4HKsfaHO1f5PNy10Of/4fZHTWv@/4@ONtRRMIrl0ok21VEw0VGwhPKAtLmOgi5Q0kxHAShlpKNgCOQYAnlG5iAFIGwBIkCiYHljsEILINcYIY5PCmwEWBhmkDHYOkOgDiOTWK5YAA).

#### How?

```
ŒP+⁼ƭ3\Ạ$ƇṪLạL - Link: list of integers, A
ŒP             - powerset of A -> all subsequences (Note: shortest to longest)
         Ƈ     - filter keep those for which:
        $      -   last two links as a monad:
     3\        -     three-wise overlapping reduction by:
    ƭ          -       alternate between these two links:
  +            -         add -> first plus second element of the three-slice
   ⁼           -         equals -> does that result equal the third element?
       Ạ       -       all truthy?
          Ṫ    - tail -> (one of) the longest one(s)
           L   - length
             L - length of A
            ạ  - absolute difference
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 51 bytes

```
saJ2.-{jR@f{L[2.>}f{J2CO)++~]j[-[-==}[~L[.-}{0it}IE
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxBC4JAEIXv/orBWzgj7lhZiBJEh0QIunQY9mCgkHhJ87Ssf31bjG7vve/jPedxaKf33DoTUhnmOemxcVNTcUymv586UwvHpe1MxefbJooW3QsJFYWVpZaYrEleH3u9OPsYnCgE1kAlJIHsELYIx/@iAvE5QyAv7RE8ZgTli/KNs1XiYL1ASFfh4GH6@/sC)

```
sa     # Non-destructive length 
J      # Dup
2.-    # Longer than 2
{
 j     # Reorder stack
 R@    # All subsequences
 f{    # Filter
  L[   # Length
  2.>  # >2
 }
 f{
  J    # Dup
  2CO  # Pairwise 2s
  )++  # Map sum
  ~]   # Drop last
  j    # Reorder stack
  [-[- # Drop first twice
  ==   # Are equal
 }
 [~    # Last
 L[    # Length
 .-    # Difference with original
}
{
 0it   # Return 0
}IE    # If else
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>14</s> 13 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
æʒD¥¦Å?}ζ‚€gÆ
```

-1 byte thanks to *@ovs*

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ATkAxv9vc2FiaWX//8OmypJEwqXCpsOFP33OtuKAmuKCrGfDhv//WzksNywtMSw2LDUsMiwxMSwxNiwyN10) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXL/8PLTk1yObT00LLDrfa157Y9apj1qGlN@uG2/zr/o6MNdYxidaJNdUx0LMEsSx1zHV1DHTMdUx0jHUNDHUMzHSNzsDgEmuvAWNhUAVlAASMdYyA0BfONdcxiYwE).

**Explanation:**

```python
æ             # Get the powerset of the (implicit) input-list
 ʒ            # Filter to check if it's Fibonacci-like:
  D           #  Duplicate the current list
   ¥          #  Pop one and get its forward differences
    ¦         #  Remove the first item
     Å?       #  Check if the original list starts with this as sublist
       }ζ     # After the filter: zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns, with " "
              # as implicit default filler for unequal length lists
         ‚    # Pair the (implicit) input-list with this matrix
          €g  # Get the length of both
            Æ # Reduce by subtracting
              # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Because we only care about the length, the zip/transpose with filler is used to our advantage to get the length of the longest truthy result of the filter (thanks to *@ovs*).

Comment: `æéʒ...}θ` can be shortened to `æʒ...}ζ`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ü∞♀ÇjäεîVÖ₧"╥←
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=81ec0c806a84ee8c56999e22d21b&i=%5B1,+2%5D%0A%5B5,+4,+9,+2%5D%0A%5B9,+7,+-1,+6,+5,+2,+11,+16,+27%5D%0A%5B9,+9,+9,+9,+7,+9,+9,+9,+9,+-1,+6,+5,+2,+11,+16,+27%5D&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 47 bytes

```
{(#x)-|/{(#x)**/(-2_x)=2_-':x}'(,()){x,x,'y}/x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJwdyUEKgCAQRuG9p/ihhY4oMlMpCZ3FnWeYMO+etHrwvV6H25Tim/56n1yUpnRLi7bqtC44oqFBg31m0mlMx4WCyMg4IWAGZ0hZzthxrMf8AcetFBM=)

Wow this is a long one. I tried to emulate APL's `(⊢,,¨)\` with `(,()){x,x,'y}/`. Actually the whole code is almost a port of ovs's answer into ngn/k.

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.combinatorics`, 81 bytes

```factor
[ dup all-subsets [ dup differences rest head? ] find-last nip [ length ] bi@ - ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY8xDsIwDEX3nuJfoEipgAoYYEMsLIgJdUhbFyLSEGJ3QIizl0ARYsBevt/zYDe6kkvo97vNdj1Hq@U0qi5taZyO2FSMMwVHdjAsWgzLCzNdO3IV8dvABxK5@WCcYJEk9wSx7lDI8PjkCcaY/cwz5EgVplFkUApqiiz/sUPn3/Rv95H0B9Sdh7Y25a5kEsZAatM0FIYTA7HgRLpeokBjXJ1aHYkzPi5bcsf4QYHSrJCi6FvtMeqf)