# Find the coefficients of a rational generating function

Tags: code-golf, math, integer, polynomials

If we write a sequence of numbers as the coefficients of a power series, then that power series is called the (ordinary) **generating function** (or G.f.) of that sequence. That is, if for some function `F(x)` and series of integers `a(n)` we have:

```
a(0) + a(1)x + a(2)x^2 + a(3)x^3 + a(4)x^4 + ... = F(x)
```

Then `F(x)` is the generating function of `a`. For example, the [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) tells us that:

```
1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + ... = 1/(1-x)
```

So the generating function of `1, 1, 1, ...` is `1/(1-x)`. If we differentiate both sides of the equation above and multiply by `x` we get the following equality:

```
x + 2x^2 + 3x^3 + 4x^4 + ... = x/(1-x)^2
```

So the generating function of `1, 2, 3, ...` is `x/(1-x)^2`. Generating functions are a very powerful tool, and you can do many useful things with them. A short introduction can be found [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2005/readings/ln11.pdf), but for a really thorough explanation there is the amazing book generatingfunctionology.

---

In this challenge you will take [a rational function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function) (the quotient of two polynomials with integer coefficients) as input as two arrays of integer coefficients, first the numerator then the denominator. For example the function `f(x) = x / (1 - x - x^2)` will be encoded as `[0, 1], [1, -1, -1]` in the input.

Given this input your program must infinitely print the coefficients of the power series that equals the generating function, one per line, starting at the coefficient of `x`, then `x^2`, etc.

---

Examples:

```
[1], [1, -1] -> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...
[1], [2, -2] -> 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, ...
[0, 1], [1, -2, 1] -> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ...
[0, 1], [1, -1, -1] -> 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, ...
[1], [1, -2] -> 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, ...
[0, 1, 1], [1, -3, 3, -1] -> 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, ...
```

Comment: Crap, my language is built for sequences this, but I can't really do multidimensional array input :(

Comment: @StepHen What input would work for your language?

Comment: It's not a flaw in the challenge, it's a flaw in the language. I don't have the ability to process input of variable length yet :P

Comment: I'm really just not mathematically-minded enough for this spec, any chance you could post more of a layman's explanation for us common folk?

Comment: @Mayube I added another general example at the top of my challenge. If it's still unclear I can suggest reading the linked introduction. Generating functions are a simple concept, but may seem magic to those unfamiliar.

Comment: Is it acceptable to use a descending degree order of coefficients? e.g. `x^3+2x^2+1` yields `[1, 2, 0 ,1]`

Comment: @KeyuGan That is fine, as long as you clearly state it in your answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate Power Series Coefficients](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/105282/calculate-power-series-coefficients)

Comment: @trichoplax That always forces the numerator to be 1, which is not the same. For example it cannot express my last example, the squares.

Comment: An alternative way of phrasing this is that it evaluates a general linear recurence. In that way it generalises [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/85727/194), and might serve as a dupe target for future recurrence questions.

Comment: @orlp thanks for explaining the difference - makes sense now.

Comment: Is it 1-indexed or 0 indexed? If it is 1-indexed, then the output for `[1], [1, -2]` should be `2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, ...`. If it is 0-indexed, then the output for `[0, 1], [1, -2, 1]` should be `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ...`.

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 63 bytes

```hs
z=0:z
(a:b)%y@(c:d)=a/c:zipWith(-)(b++z)(map(a/c*)d++z)%y
_%_=z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYk5CsMwFAV7n@IVEXzFViIT3AgEuUDqFMaI7wUsvGASNdblFQWmmGFm/i7TuqYUrTaxIDa9FOeTBjNKy/fBRH@8fZhJSerLMkra@KA8rnL8pzgLJ5yNaWO/wyLfl8Px8XvADYGXCY3GBa2uUGc6CLRZ1KNCRtVd@gE)

Defines an operator `%` returning an infinite lazy list of coefficients. The list is zero-indexed, so the constant coefficient is included.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 64 <del>83</del> <del>90</del> bytes

```
Do[Echo@Limit[D[#/#2/i!&@@Fold[x#+#2&]/@#,{x,i}],x->0],{i,∞}‌​]&
```

Thanks to @ngenisis and @Jenny_mathy !

Take input as two lists.

Need `Alt+.` to terminate the execution to see the result. Frontend may crash due to rapid output.

83 bytes version (@Jenny_mathy):

```
i=1;v=Tr[#*x^Range@Length@#]&;While[1<2,Echo@Limit[D[v@#/v@#2/i!,{x,i}],x->0];i++]&
```

Comment: 83 bytes:   i = 1;
v = Tr[#*x^Range@Length@#] &; 
While[1 < 2, Echo@Limit[D[v@#/v@#2/i!, {x, i}], x -> 0]; i++] &

Comment: @Jenny_mathy Sorry for bothering. I figure it out that there's some junk invisible Unicode characters in your first comment. Once cleaned up, the code is OK.

Comment: `64` bytes: `Do[Echo@Limit[D[#/#2/i!&@@Fold[x#+#2&]/@#,{x,i}],x->0],{i,∞}]&`. This assumes the input is a list of two lists and the coefficients are in order of descending degree. The only built-in I know of to do what `v` does is `Internal\`FromCoefficientList`

Comment: Does running this repeatedly work? I think a couple of extra parentheses might be necessary to put `i` inside the lambda. (On the other hand, I'm not really sure whether the ability to run repeatedly is relevant when the goal is to print an infinite list…has there been a meta consensus on this?)

Comment: @ngenisis: What version are you using? On v10.0, your solution gives me `Iterator {i,∞} does not have appropriate bounds`.

Comment: @JulianWolf 11.1

Comment: `x^Range@Length@#.#&`  saves 4 bytes.  Also I think you can do `For` instead of `While` and save 2 more.`

Comment: @JulianWolf `Do` seems to support `Infinity` on 10.2

Comment: @KeyuGan: Thanks. I guess I'm just a couple minor versions early, then.

Answer (score 1):

### CJam (22 bytes)

```
{\{(W$(@\/_pW*f*.+1}g}
```

[Online demo](https://tio.run/##S85KzP0fbaBgqGAYqxBtqKBrrGCsoGsY@786plojXEXDIUY/viBcK01LT9uwNr32f91/AA). Note that as many of the existing answers, this includes the 0th coefficient in the output.

#### Dissection

```
{           e# Define a block which takes numerator N and denominator D as arguments
  \         e# Flip to put D at the bottom, since that won't change
  {         e# Infinite loop:
    (       e#   Pop the first element of (the modified) N
    W$(     e#   Copy D and pop its first element
            e#   Stack: D N[1:] N[0] D[1:] D[0]
    @\/     e#   Bring N[0] to top, flip, divide
            e#   Stack: D N[1:] D[1:] N[0]/D[0]
    _p      e#   Print a copy
    W*f*.+  e#   Multiply by -1, multiply all, pointwise add
            e#   Stack: D N[1:]-(N[0]/D[0])*D[1:]
  1}g
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, <s>86</s> 79 bytes

```
f=x^Range@Length@#.#&;For[n=1,8>3,Print@SeriesCoefficient[f@#/f@#2,{x,0,n++}]]&
```

Takes input as two separate lists (numerator coefficients, denominator coefficients).
If the input can be taken directly as a fraction of polynomials rather than as lists of coefficients, this can be shortened significantly.

It seems that `Do` can work with infinite bounds in v11.
I can't test this locally, but, if this is the case, then this solution can be shortened to **75 bytes**:

```
f=x^Range@Length@#.#&;Do[Print@SeriesCoefficient[f@#/f@#2,{x,0,n}],{n,∞}]&
```

Comment: last test case doesn't begin with 0.

Comment: @Jenny_mathy: shoot, thanks for the heads up. Looks like the test cases expect starting from the first in stead of the zeroth…pretty sure this should let me save a few bytes.

Comment: @Jenny_mathy: I think the test cases might be wonky. Starting `n` from 1 in stead of `0`, this gives the same results as your solution; both fail, though, on the second to last test case, which this solution passes when starting `n` from 0.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 23 bytes

```
JE#
KchQhJ=t-M.t,Q*LKJ0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/38tVmcs7OSMww8u2RNdXr0QnUMvH28vg//9oAx0FQyCK5YoGUrrGOgpApGsYCwA)

#### How it works

```
                       Q = eval(input())
JE                     J = eval(input())
  #                    infinite loop:
 chQhJ                   Q[0]/J[0]
K                        assign that to K (and print it, because of the preceding newline)
              *LKJ       K times every element of J
            ,Q           [Q, that]
          .t      0      transpose, padding with 0s
        -M               subtract each pair
       t                 remove the first element
      =                  assign that back to Q
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 66 bytes

```
p->q->for(i=0,oo,print(Pol(Polrev(p)/(Polrev(q)+O(x*x^i)))\x^i%x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYc7CoAwEAWvkkbY1Swq1skVtPcDFkYCYtYgktvHtRDmMfN4jZ52zk4ZlZnsRdaFCN40OgTN0Z83DOH4FrcHGOs/L6x6SGVaPCJOoiIhZgdjo1UrzAijmDqtBJKfXw)